# Is it still useful to load the lmodern package?

Tags: fonts, latin-modern, computer-modern

A few years ago, the `lmodern` package was a good way to have high quality fonts by simply adding :

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Nowadays, `lmodern` seems less popular. I'm wondering if it is because LaTeX default fonts received some improvements which make `lmodern` useless? Or because the package is abandoned? It hard to see if the package is still developed ([a search on CTAN about `lmodern`](http://www.ctan.org/search.html?phrase=lmodern&ext=true&PORTAL=on&PKG=on&AUTHORS=on&TOPICS=on&max=16) does not return anything) and `texdoc lmodern` is not helpful...

So :

1. Is it still useful to load the `lmodern` package?
2. What are the effects/advantages of this package compared to normal (default) CM fonts?

Comment: I use it because `\textasciitilde` produces a high tilde in the default computer modern, but centred in lmodern.

Comment: Related: [Latin Modern vs cm-super?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390/4012). My point about [the German sharp s ⟨ß⟩ and accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65103/4012) still holds, which would be a reason to use `lmodern` for me.

Comment: Yes! One more obvious enhancement of `lmodern` I noticed on the default computer modern is its sans serif font type. You can obvious see the difference of large bold sans serif texts, e.g. chapter titles.

Comment: However, `lmodern` does not have bold small caps, right? It is the only thing making me not want to use it :(

Comment: Another drawback is that some outdated or buggy PDF software (e.g.\ SumatraPDF 3.2 but not 3.3.3) cannot search text if you use lmodern - those readers insert spaces after most letters.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are so many fonts similar to Computer Modern (CM) now, a FAQ like the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq) might be valuable. Pending that, the answers to your two questions might be

1. yes,
2. Type 1 (T1) or OpenType (OTF) access to a moderate set of CM-like glyphs, without going into the extremely large `cm-super` set.

For what it's worth, I use the `lmodern` package for most of my documents. One day I'll graduate to something more exotic...

Comment: You can access slightly more exotic features of Latin Modern using cfr-lm. lmodern is better for some uses, though, notably if preparing documents for conversion with tex4ht. (I am not sure why but cfr-lm causes the conversion not to work properly, possibly due to use of virtual fonts - not sure.) Disclaimer: I wrote cfr-lm. (I primarily wanted access to the different styles of figures, variant styles etc. which are in the fonts but not supported by lmodern.)

Comment: TeX FAQ link is dead.

Answer (score 25):

Well, none of the two most common LaTeX distributions use Latin Modern by default, they still keep Computer Modern (as of November 2013). So yes, calling `\usepackage{lmodern}` is still advised, unless you find `cm-super` (which is another fork of Computer Modern fonts) more convenient.

Comment: In what sense is it still "advised"? What makes the Latin Modern font preferable to Computer Modern?

Comment: @jvriesem I know it's a while since you asked this question, but here's one reason: If you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with Computer Modern, it uses bitmap fonts which end up pixelated. Latin Modern doesn't suffer from this problem.