# Change structure of itemize/enumerate

Tags: errors, enumerate

I have the following code, which runs and formats nicely.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Examples}
For each function $f$ given,
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Sketch the graph of $f.$
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is continuous.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is increasing.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is decreasing.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is concave up.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is concave down.
\end{enumerate}

\item $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x+1.$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-2x+2}{x-1}.$
\item $f(x)=x\sqrt{3-x}.$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{36}\sqrt{7-x}.$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But it gives a missing \item error.  The result,

[image: output]

How should I edit the code to avoid the error, yet keep the same format and output?

Comment: I tried to compile your document. It's by far not minimal and it stops due to some issue with `xy` package. Now, commenting that out, the remaining issue is, that `enumerate` expects an `\item`, not another `\begin{enumerate}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've edited out the unnecessary packages. Minimal as much as possible to show the output I want.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer which is why I asked the question!

Comment: Well, `lmodern` is certainly unnecessary as it will have no effect at all on your document. `mathtools` loads `amsmath` anyway. Better `xcolor` than `color`. Also, it would be better to use `scrbook` with `classicthesis`. It would also be better not to use `classicthesis`, but that's a different issue. Finally, `tabu` cannot be recommended if you hope your document will remain compilable in the future as the author has promised backwards incompatible changes. Once that happens, documents which use it will break.

Comment: And how is `appendix` necessary here? Or `hyperref`? You don't really need anything except the document class and `enumitem`, do you?

Comment: @cfr you are right.  I got in a hurry when editing.

Comment: for those interested, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147194/is-it-still-useful-to-load-the-lmodern-package

Comment: @JohnMolokach That link suggests that you have misunderstood me. 99% of my documents use Latin Modern (though I unsurprisingly use `cfr-lm` rather than `lmodern`). But loading `lmodern` ***has no effect on your document***. Use the properties listing in your PDF viewer or run `pdffonts <filename>.pdf` to see what fonts you are actually getting. There is no Latin Modern there. I ran your example just to make sure before I commented earlier and not one Latin Modern font is used.

Comment: @cfr I did not mean the link to be a rebuttal.  Just thought I'd share for those wondering why lmodern was used.  You are right it was not needed for this example.

Comment: @JohnMolokach It will have no effect on your thesis, either. The fonts you are getting are specified in `classicthesis`. Loading `lmodern` beforehand makes no difference. `lmodern` overwrites the defaults. Then `classicthesis` overwrites them all over again. It won't do any harm - it is just pointless and misleading if it makes you think you are getting LM. (You are getting a mixture of Computer Modern and various postscript fonts in the above MWE.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, I've deleted \lmodern from the preamble and after recompiling I see no difference. It was in the book template I got from share latex.

Comment: @JohnMolokach Never trust templates ;). We... er... when somebody says they are using a template, you know that there's trouble brewing. I've not seen one question involving a template where the template wasn't at least half of the problem. `classicthesis` itself is usually about 95% of the problem in questions which use it. This question is rather unusual in that `classicthesis` itself is not actually involved in the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with a simple empty `\item`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Examples}
For each function $f$ given,
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[]%
        \begin{enumerate}[before = \vspace*{-\topsep}]
          \item Sketch the graph of $f.$
          \item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is continuous.
          \item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is increasing.
          \item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is decreasing.
          \item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is concave up.
          \item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is concave down.
        \end{enumerate}

  \item $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x+1.$
  \item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-2x+2}{x-1}.$
  \item $f(x)=x\sqrt{3-x}.$
  \item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{36}\sqrt{7-x}.$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, and carries even closer to my vertical spacing from before - but i wouldn't have known how to deal with the \vspace command you used.

Comment: All lists add a `\topsep`  vertical spacing at the beginning at at the end. I simply neutralised it at the top.

Comment: because empty item would add a space there, right?

Comment: No it doen'st, if there is nothing after (that's the reason of the `%`: prevent any unwanted space). It's the nested enumerate that adds \topsep – as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\section*{Examples}
For each function $f$ given,
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),leftmargin=2\leftmargini]
\item Sketch the graph of $f.$
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is continuous.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is increasing.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is decreasing.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is concave up.
\item Write the open intervals for which $f$ is concave down.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item $f(x)=x^3-x^2-x+1.$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-2x+2}{x-1}.$
\item $f(x)=x\sqrt{3-x}.$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{36}\sqrt{7-x}.$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I liked the elimination of topsep as it keeps the original formatting I had earlier in that regard. Thanks though for your answer!