# Low quality font using xwatermark, TikZ and \newsavebox in combination with [T1]{fontenc} and lmodern

Tags: tikz-pgf, font-encodings, lmodern, xwatermark

Some time ago at the link [Transparent foreground watermark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/transparent-foreground-watermark), I learned from Gonzalo Medina's answer how to make transparent water maker with the package `xwatermark`. And it was awesome.

On the other hand, I learned about the usage of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to enable some features with accented characters, which is indeed very useful for me, a Portuguese LaTeX user.

First I thought [T1] fonts was useless and it only make the font looks ugly (big pixels), but than I found the others usages at [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc). I could finally copy and paste characters from the PDF, which is indeed useful.
The solution for the "ugliness" came from the package `lmodern` in [Is it still useful to load the lmodern package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147194/is-it-still-useful-to-load-the-lmodern-package).

And this point I was quite happy with the features but never had to use them together. Until last week when I used the transparent `xwatermark`, which is made using TikZ, in combination with `[T1]{fontenc}` and `lmodern` and then I realized the "ugliness" came back.

At first glance I thought it could be some issue from the packages `xwatermark` or TikZ. But it doesn't seem to be the case. The `tikzpicture` environment and the `\newwatermark` command of Example 2 in the MWE below led me to this hypothesis. The `\newwatermark` in Example 1 shows the "ugliness" issue. Maybe it is something related to the `\newsavebox` but I didn't find anything that could have helped me.

I would like to know why this happens and also if there is some solution to good looking water marks alongside the features from the package `fontenc`.

A MWE with both approaches is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}

% -------------------------
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Problem is independent from latin1 or utf8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Enables Copy and Paste of special characters
\usepackage{lmodern} % Makes [T1] letters pretty again
% -------------------------

% ========== 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} % No PSTRICKS solutions please
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
% ========== 

% ========== Example 1 
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/transparent-foreground-watermark
% It has opacity. The text behind is readable but loses quality when used with [T1]]{fontenc} and {lmodern}
% ----------
\newsavebox\myboxb\savebox\myboxb{\tikz[color=blue!80,opacity=0.4]\node{\huge{Example 1}};}
\newwatermark*[allpages, angle=45, scale=7, xpos=-20, ypos=+060]{\usebox\myboxb}

% ========== Example 2
% It has no opacity. The text behind is not always readable and it never loses quality regardless of [T1]]{fontenc} and {lmodern}
% ----------
\newwatermark*[allpages, color=blue!80, angle=45, scale=7, xpos=-10, ypos=-30]{\huge{Example 2}}
% ========== 

\begin{document}
\section{Título -- Title}

Characters to test copy and paste: áéíóú, ãõ, âêô, à, äöü.

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) node[below]{$x$ -- There is no problem between TikZ and [T1]fontenc} -- (0,1)node[above]{\huge{Example Ti\textit{k}Z} works fine};
    \node at (3,0.5) {\Huge{Direct Node}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The first figure show the whole PDF and the second shows the zoom into the letters.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the box with the text in the preamble. At this time the fonts are not yet setup.

Better move this behind `\begin{document}`:

```
\newsavebox\myboxb\savebox\myboxb{\tikz[color=blue!80,opacity=0.4]\node{\huge{Example 1}};}
```

You should also install with the package manager of your tex system the `cm-super` package. Then you will get type1 fonts also without lmodern.

Comment: Thank you very much Mrs. Fischer. It worked. I would never imagine the definition of \newsavebox should be after \begin{document}.

Comment: I installed the package cm-super. With this package I got good looking fonts whether I placed the command `\newsavebox` i.e., after or behind the `\begin{document}`.
Placing it before `\begin{document}` seems much better to keep my text code organized. Thanks once again.

Comment: if you put the newsavebox in the preamble your example 1 will use a different font. With lmodern this is not noticable as lmodern and cm are quite similar, but try with `\usepackage[default]{roboto} ` instead of lmodern.

Comment: Ok. I tested and it happened what you said. The combinations are very clear now.