# Problem copying text from latex PDF - special characters

Tags: pdf, characters

I am using LaTeX in a portuguese document, with special characters such as tilde or cedilla. I have a sample document with the following content:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

é canção

\end{document}
```

My editor (TeXworks) is configured to use UTF8, and the resultant PDF shows the right result, as seen on the following image:

[image: Generated PDF]

My problem is: when I copy the text from the PDF I get weird characters, and not the text that is exhibited. How to overcome this?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that 
● [never use the solution suggested below `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470976/250119)
● that solution only works for characters that is actually included in T1 encoding, so for example `ṃ` will still not work, refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22213/250119) for a solution. ● [another related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115080/250119)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use T1 font encoding with support for special characters:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me: I have \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} both specified, but I still can't copy say, $\gamma$ out of the resulting PDF.

Comment: @Canageek: $\gamma$ is not text, it's a math symbol of a math font. However,you could try the same if you use the Unicode text gamma γ.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Crud, that removes the ease of inserting greek characters from LaTeX as I have to go find a source for them then.

Comment: @Canageek: get just one Greek alphabet, such as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Main_letters), or use a Greek keyboard. If you really mean math font letters, I suggest you post a new question instead of a comment.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically