# How to get accented unicode characters that can be copy-pasted?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, unicode, accents

The aim is to generate the .pdf with accented characters (the .tex file has mixed macro and unicode input), in a way that the .pdf text can be copy-pasted.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

Unicode input: ā ī ū ṃ ṅ ñ

Macro input: \=a \={\i} \=u \d{m} \.n \~n

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex`, the above will visually produce the desired characters, but when you select and copy-paste them from the .pdf, you get

```
Unicode input: a  ̄ u m n ñ
 ̄ı ̄ .  ̇
Macro input: a  ̄ u m n ñ
```

**Edit:**
Ulrike's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22213/how-to-output-non-compound-accented-unicode-characters-with-pdflatex/22218#22218) explains what `pdflatex` is doing here.

Comment: Crosslink to related question. [ligatures - Cannot copy text from the simplest PDF file? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115080/cannot-copy-text-from-the-simplest-pdf-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the path to victory:

1. Install **TeX Live 2010** which has a `luatex` and `fontspec` version that work together. Follow the instructions on [tug.org](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).
2. On Linux, don't forget to update the `$PATH`! If you already have TeX Live installed with your package manager, give the new path priority over the old one. For example, at the end of `~/.bashrc`, put `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH`
3. Log out and back in (or just open a new terminal) so that your `$PATH` updates.

Save this test to `test.tex` somewhere, and compile with
`lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

Unicode input: ā ī ū ṃ ṅ ñ

Macro input: \=a \={\i} \=u \d{m} \.n \~n

\end{document}
```

Open the resulting `test.pdf`, and when you copy-paste from it, you get

```
Unicode input: ā ī ū ṃ ṅ ñ
Macro input: ā ī ū ṃ ṅ ñ
```

Nice!

Answer (score 11):

pdflatex doesn't use "unicode compounds". You are using T1-encoding and for the accented chars not available in this encoding pdflatex use various methods to build them. E.g the dot below the m is actually a small tabular with the m in the first row and a dot in the second:

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\d}{T1}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
```

In theory you can get correct glyphs with pdflatex (if your font contains them). In practice it would mean a lot work. Better use xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: With XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, use, accordingly, `\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[EU2]{fontenc}`, or just load `fontspec`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I removed the latter part of the question accordingly. I see that I'll need to update `lualatex` to work with `fontspec`.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `\usepackage{cmap}`. Or switch to xelatex/lualatex.

Comment: Thanks! There should be a phrase on this site for the "yet another latex package I didn't know about" feeling.

Comment: Did *"cmap"* work for anybody?  It's been 11 years (to the day!), and I still can't copy extended latin characters properly using _pdftex_ =)
I guess it's time to switch to XeTeX for good.

Comment: According to [`cmap`'s documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmap), it only works if the character is already in the specified encoding, so this solution is useless in this case where `ṃ` isn't even included in T1 encoding.