# Cannot copy text from the simplest PDF file?

Tags: pdf, ligatures, copy-paste

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   We define multiplication by
   $$v_1x = 0,\quad v_2x = v_1,\quad v_1y = -v_1,\quad v_2y = v_1$$
\end{document}
```

which looks like this

> [image]

It's as simple as it gets, but when I copy the content of the PDF I get:

```
We de??ne multiplication by
v1x = 0; v2x = v1; v1y = ??v1; v2y = v1
1
```

So there are 4 errors:

1. The **fi** in **define** disappears
2. , becomes ;
3. The minus sign is not being copied properly
4. Another 1 appears at the very end of the copied text

How can I prevent this from happening? I use Texmaker with Miktex 2.9 and pdfLatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which PDF viewing program do you use? BTW, the final `1` is probably the page number...

Comment: I tried it with Adobe Reader X and Google Chrome's internal PDF Viewer. And yes, the 1 at the end seems to be the page number. ^^

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Unicode mapping based on font encoding

Packages `cmap` or `mmap` add information about glyph to Unicode conversions into the PDF file based on the used TeX encoding. The hooks into the font loading mechanism of LaTeX and should be used as early as possible, e.g.:

```
\RequirePackage{mmap}% (\usepackage does not work before \documentclass)
\documentclass{article}
```

Package `mmap` is used here, because it has better math support AFAIK.

### Unicode mapping based on glyph name

An alternative is a feature of pdfTeX that adds the mapping to Unicode based on the name of the glyph in the font. Therefore it does not work for PK fonts, because they do not contain glyph names.

```
\pdfgentounicode=1 %    
\input{glyphtounicode}
```

Caution: Package `cmap` or `mmap` cannot be used together with `\pdfgentounicode`. The result would be a duplicated entry in the font data dictionary. This is not allowed in the [PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> Note: No two entries in the same dictionary should have the same key.
>   If a key does appear more than once, its value is undefined.

And copy&paste yield a random result depends on the PDF viewer.

### Font encoding

Especially if you have accented characters or more special symbols you should consider using `T1` font encoding. The default encoding for LaTeX is `OT1` that support 7-bit only (max. 128 glyphs). Accented characters are constructed, that's bad for copy&paste:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

You should have installed the `cm-super` font bundle that contain Type 1 versions of the EC fonts. Or use the modern Latin Modern fonts. They descend from the CM/EC fonts.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: \RequirePackage{mmap} seems to does the job, although I still get the error message http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/2307/errorux.jpg in Adobe Reader. May I ask why this is a "feature" of latex? Surely, the intention of latex cannot be to make copy/paste faulty.

Comment: What exactly are PK fonts, what would be an example of one?

Comment: @doncherry For example, if you use the EC fonts (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` without further font package) without having `cm-super` installed, you get PK fonts. That are bitmap fonts.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Is there a simple why to install these cm-super fonts? I.e. can I just add them via my Miktex Package Manager?

Comment: @Thomas Yes and yes.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

It worked perfectly with me. I am on mac OS (Texmaker also) and I couldn't try on windows.

Edit:

As suggested by @egreg , adding

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

might help.

Comment: It still does not copy properly (all 4 errors still occur) and additionally it looks like this when I zoom in: http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4897/blurom.jpg, i.e. no smooth edges anymore.

Comment: @Thomas You have either to install the CM-super fonts or do `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Okay, using all 3 packages solves all problems except for the *fi* problem, and now I get the following error message when copying: http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/2307/errorux.jpg

Comment: @Thomas maybe try latin1 instead of utf8.

Comment: @LouisG Same issues, sadly. :/

Comment: I tried to copy-paste from adobe reader and I have an issue with the "-" (but not the "fi")... But no problem with chrome and preview (pdf reader built in mac os). This makes me think that the problem comes maybe from adobe... Have you tried with another pdf reader (like foxit) ?

Comment: Adobe gives an error, Chrome has still trouble with the "fi" and Foxit works, although when I copy from Foxit every letter is a new line, e.g. after copying the word "define" becomes d e f i n e (where each space is a line break). It's just so confusing...