# produce copy-paste-able pdf output with correct indentation with listing

Tags: listings, python

Here is a block of latex code to produce some Python code.  I'd like to be able to copy and paste it into Python.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Python,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false
}

\begin{lstlisting}
def test(inputvariable):
    if inputvariable == 4:
        print("The input variable is 4 .")
        print("So I'm giving this response.")
    print("done with if statement.")

test(4)
test(3)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It looks right:
[image]
Unfortunately when I copy and paste it, the indentation is lost, and that's pretty key to how Python works.

Is it possible to get the spacing to appear when I copy/paste it?

Comment: Just... don't: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195495/21891

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inho it is not really possible in a reliable way. It depends too much on the pdf viewer. It is possible to insert real spaces with the `\pdffakespace` primitive, but the indentation is preserved in sumatra only if I map the space (globally!) to the `Unicode Character 'FIGURE SPACE' (U+2007)`, and in the adobe reader it still disappears.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}
    {\def\lst@outputspace{ \pdffakespace}}
\makeatother

\input{glyphtounicode}

% saner but doesn't work
%\pdfglyphtounicode{space}{0020}

% works in sumatra:
\pdfglyphtounicode{space}{2007}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Python,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showspaces,
  showstringspaces=false
}


\begin{lstlisting}
def test(inputvariable):
    if inputvariable == 4:
        print("The input variable is 4 .")
        print("So I'm giving this response.")
    print("done with if statement.")

test(4)
test(3)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: {nodding vigorously}

Comment: I'd be very interested to see a recap of the available options:  there's `\pdffakespace`, `\pdfinterwordspaceon`, the `accsup` package, and they all seem to do slightly different things. @UlrikeFischer, do you know how Chromium's "print to PDF" feature works? It produces PDFs with spaces that evince has no trouble copying, whereas all other solutions that I've seen failed with Evince.