# Listing cut and paste in PDF

Tags: listings, pdf, copy-paste

I am trying to get good copy-n-paste'able text from a LaTeX generated PDF using the listings package.

I have three listings that all behave not as I'd like:

1. Long lines are broken using `breaklines` and when copy-n-pasted the linebreak is also copied (tested in Preview and Adobe). I'd like it to NOT copy the line break (see example in MWE).
2. Correctly indented and spaced listings are displayed differently when cut-n-pasted.

For example, this listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Initial base.tf configuration}, language=java]
    provider "aws" {
      access_key = "abc123"
      secret_key = "abc123"
      region     = "us-east-1"
    }
\end{lstlisting}
```

Becomes:

```
provider "aws" { access_key = "abc123" secret_key = "abc123" region = "us-east-1"
}
```

I've cut down my doc to an MWE.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

% fonts
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

% Listings
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newfontfamily{\lstsansserif}[Scale=.85]{DejaVuSansMono}

\lstset{
caption=\lstname,
fancyvrb=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\linespread{0.9}\lstsansserif,
tabsize=2,
numbers=none,
upquote=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
literate={-}{-}1,
breakatwhitespace=false,
escapechar=\&,
columns=fullflexible,
keepspaces=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, caption={Download the Terraform zip file}, language=bash]
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.7.7/terraform_0.7.7_linux_amd64.zip
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, caption={The base README.md file}, language=bash]

# Our first AWS configuration for Terraform

An initial configuration for Terraform.

## Usage

    $ terraform apply

## License

MIT

\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Initial base.tf configuration}, language=java]
    provider "aws" {
      access_key = "abc123"
      secret_key = "abc123"
      region     = "us-east-1"
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323294/produce-copy-paste-able-pdf-output-with-correct-indentation-with-listing

Comment: [This answer to "How to copy/paste multiple spaces from lstlistings?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195495/110998) is quite instructive. My conclusion from it is that encouraging people to copy and paste code from a pdf is a bad idea (independently of whether TeX was involved in the creation of the pdf or not).