# pandoc *.md to *.pdf with code block that keeps spaces/tabs

Tags: pdf, code, pandoc, markdown

I'm using the following command line to generate a `*.pdf` file from my `*.md` file:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex file.md -o file.pdf
```

Everything works fine except **when I copy-paste a code block** from the generated `*.pdf`. It then **loses its spaces/tabs** and so the following if statement:

```
if (i<j)
{
    i=i+5;
}
```

becomes

```
if (i<j)
{
i=i+5;
}
```

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Even for a simple  markdown file with an alleged simple code block, please add a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we can reproduce exactly the problem.  As is, your code produce really`if (i<j) { i=i+5; }` in a single line. Having to guess what really you could be doing does not help.

Comment: Not really feasible: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323354/29873