# Produce copy-paste friendly code blocks in PDFs

Tags: pdftex, verbatim, code, sourcecode, copy-paste

I have used `lslisting` for inserting the code blocks. Requirement is to make the code blocks displayed correctly in the compiled PDF and make them as easy as possible to copy as plain text. Please take a look at the following in order to demonstrate the problem,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  gobble=8,
  tabsize=4,
  language=bash,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        test $(ls -la) = $(ls -l) 
    \end{lstlisting}
    \begin{verbatim}
        test $(ls -la) = $(ls -l) 
    \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF]

When I copy the output generated by `lslisting`, what I get is the following plain text:

```
test$(ls -la) =$(ls -l)
```

Problems with that are white spaces before '$' character go missing for some reason, also it's hard to copy in the sense that 'triple click highlight' to select the block/line doesn't work.

When I copy the output generated by `verbatim`, I get the block of text as plain text correctly as following and the also 'triple click' seems to work.

```
test $(ls -la) = $(ls -l)
```

But the problem with that is I can't use `gobble=8` to correct the relative indentation and the formatting possibilities are also limited.

I also want to mention that I'm aware that the PDF viewers also play a role here but what I need is something that supports most PDF viewers generally like `verbatim` does but with the formatting possibilities. I think it should be possible because if `verbatim` can do that, why can't we add onto it? Is there any better alternative to `lslisting`

Something like below (GitHub Markdown) would be ideal although 'copy' button might not be possible but at least text might be,

[image: MD]

Comment: you can't. Copy & paste is not reliable.  If you want the exact code embed a file into the pdf. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323354/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472112/2388