# XeLaTeX oldstyle figures search/copy

Tags: copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small-caps, old-style numbers, and some ligatures produce odd symbols in PDF copy text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49502/small-caps-old-style-numbers-and-some-ligatures-produce-odd-symbols-in-pdf-cop)

How can I make XeLaTeX produce PDFs that can be searched/copied? In particular, oldstyle figures don't work for the OpenType fonts I've tested. This my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{cmap}
\documentclass{article}

%\input{glyphtounicode} % gives me an error
%\pdfgentounicode=1  % gives me an error

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  ]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}
Testing 12345678910\\
\textsc{Testing 12345678910}
\end{document}
```

As you see, I've included the `cmap` package, as well as `glyphtounicode`, as most answers in this forum recommend. However, when inputing `glyphtounicode`, with or without the `\pdfgentounicode=1` command, produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \pdfglyphtounicode
                       {A}{0041}
```

Comment: I don't think `cmap` is compatible with XeLaTeX: "[The cmap package provides character map tables, which make PDF files generated by **pdfLaTeX** both searchable and copy-able](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap)".

Comment: @doncherry. Yeah, I think you're right.