# \pdfglyphtounicode with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, ligatures, libertine

One well known problem with using the font Linux Libertine (presumably other fonts too), is that its many ligatures are not recognized in the resulting pdf-file, so that it's not possible to search for or copy a ligature such as 'Th'.

One way of fixing this is addressed in the question [Make ligatures in Linux Libertine copyable (and searchable)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/make-ligatures-in-linux-libertine-copyable-and-searchable)

But the fix addressed there doesn't work with XeTeX. Compiling Ulrike's MWE will only result in an error message

```
> Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \pdfglyphtounicode
```

So what is the best fix for XeTeX?

Comment: I don't see any problem with `fluffier soufflé fisticuffs flair`; the `\pdfglyphtounicode` trick is for `pdftex`.

Comment: Sorry, 'fX' wasn't a good example, since Linux Libertine actually maps those onto unicode ligatures. I've changed 'ff' to 'Th' now.

Comment: That seems a bug in the font.

Comment: Bug in what sense? It's the case with every ligature in Linux Libertine that's not a Unicode character (i.e. ligatures in the font's "Private Use Area").

Comment: It shouldn't matter where a ligature is; it should nevertheless map to the separate characters for search and copy.

Comment: Putting ligatures in PUA is problematic, they should be ununcoded with names following [Adobe Glyph Naming convention](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/archives/glyph.html), so it is definitely a font *issue* (calling it a bug is too strong, the font is perfectly valid nevertheless).

Comment: How is an issue with the ligatures in a widely used LaTeX font "too localized"? Given the popularity of the question I linked to, which addresses a similar issue with the same font, it is clearly potentially useful to future visitors too.

Comment: @Sverre: Is far as I know you can't do anything on the xe(la)tex side. xetex can't manipulate the glyph names. (There is a similar problem with oldstyle numbers). Write the maintainers of the fonts. They should adjust the fonts so that they follow the conventions mentioned by Khaled.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/why-are-questions-on-package-bugs-issues-too-localized

Comment: @KhaledHosny The Linux Libertine font *has* the glyph named `T_h`, so it follows the Adobe guidelines. Thus this seems an issue in XeTeX or in `xdvipdfmx`.

Comment: @egreg: If the glyphs are encoded even if in PUA (which is the case here) the code values is used and the name will be ignored. The glyphs need to be removed from PUA and be no assigned any Unicode values at all.

Comment: It seems like doncherry reported a similar bug before? Cf. http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3575137&group_id=89513&atid=590374. Where it says "Resolution: None", although I must admit I don't understand the answer to the bug report.

Comment: It's not off-topic, because the question was how to apply the otherwise well-known command ``\pdfglyphtounicode`` in ``pdftex`` (which I linked to) to ``xetex``, where that command doesn't work. The fact that the _reason_ I want to do that is due to some (alleged) problems with the font is strictly speaking another matter. Ulrike's comment is a good answer to what I actually asked: "you can't do anything on the xe(la)tex side. xetex can't manipulate the glyph names". Both the title and the content of my question make it clear that this is about ``xetex``, thus clearly "within the scope of TeX"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XeTeX simply doesn't support the `\pdfglyphtounicode` primitive, so this route is not available. To understand why, remember that pdfTeX is 8-bit while XeTeX is natively UTF-8. AS such, it's perfectly reasonable for XeTeX to expect fonts to be 'properly' constructed to have glyphs in the appropriately-named slots and therefore to work correctly in the PDF output with no 'trickery'.

Taking the 'what to do' side of things, the problem is most likely with the font. For example, some fonts have the correct glyphs but in the 'wrong' places (*e.g.* in the Private Use Area). That's really not a 'TeX problem': all that can be done is to talk with the font designers and try to get them to fix it.

Comment: I'm answering the general XeTeX point: from discussion with the OP it's clear that this is the key part to the question, with the Libertine bit not the main focus.

Comment: A related discussion is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49502/small-caps-old-style-numbers-and-some-ligatures-produce-odd-symbols-in-pdf-cop. Where people seem to agree that the problem lies with XeTeX and not with the fonts.

Comment: Do you have any way to walk around this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574619/81293 Another problem caused by fonts.  For Times New Roman, it's none.  For most other fonts, it's `U+2010` while I'd like it to be `U+002D`, which is searchable in most PDF viewer.

Comment: A less perfect walkaround is to use `\XeTeXgenerateactualtext`.  But `/ActualText` is less well supported in most viewers on my computer.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this post is old, but for future readers' sake, I thought I'd point out that I was able to create ligatures using Linux Libertine 5.3 and XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.7.31) that are copyable and searchable when viewed in Adobe Reader 11.0.08.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Historical]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
    fluffier soufflé fisticuffs fb fh ffh fj ffj fk ffk ft fft tt Qu Th ch ck ct
\end{document}
```

You can check [my output PDF](https://jasonzentz.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/xelatexlibertineligatures.pdf) to verify that the ligatures are indeed copyable and searchable.

Does anyone know what might have changed to make this possible since the original question and answers here? Linux Libertine 5.3 (the version I used) was available at the time of the original post.

Comment: I can verify that this works on my system too now. Also with old style numerals (adding ``Numbers = OldStyle`` as an option). Some changes must have been made to either ``fontspec`` or the ``xetex`` engine.

Comment: @Sverre  It works only in Adobe Acrobat/Reader though. In Mac OS Preview the ligatures are still not recognized.  I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with ligatures for different fonts on a Mac as in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307427/fix-encoding-for-ligatures-of-fonts-in-xetex-lualatex-specifically-for-minion#) but haven't made much progress. The problem seems to be a combination of fonts/xetex/pdf-viewer.