# Why is it jaggy?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically)

With the following code, I am getting this jaggy output, which is not the purpose of using latex.

PS: This never use to happen, when I use to create other documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
...
...to write...
...still feel...
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Original Computer Modern fonts are embedded in the document in a raster format. The resolution is sufficient to print fine in most cases, but it can cause trouble when viewing on-screen, as you've found out. At the time TeX and METAFONT were designed, software rasterising was a reasonable solution.

You should use vector fonts instead, which are the way to go in the modern world. To do this, simply install the [`cm-super`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) package. Alternatively, you can try the [Latin Modern](http://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) fonts (use with `\usepackage{lmodern}`).

Comment: It never use to happen before, as in, I have create many documents, this never happened.

Comment: @Kirk: The other question suggests it is triggered by loading `fontenc`.

Comment: the T1 font encoding will make the document use the EC-fonts which are distributed as bitmap TeX fonts. Using cm-super or lmodern leads to scalable fonts in the pdf output.