# How to improve rendering

Tags: fonts, ieeetran, rendering

[image: different rendering of two different documentclasses]

The rendering above the red line(zoomed in) was a result of:
`\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`

The rendering below the red line(zoomed in) was a result of:
`\documentclass[journal]{AIAA}`

Why is there such a huge difference? Can I change something in the AIAA class file so that it yields results similar to the IEEEtran class file?

Comment: I do not have AIAA.cls, but it clearly uses bitmap fonts. Not having the document class, I am not going to provide you with a definite answer, but perhaps take a look at this article: http://dsanta.users.ch/resources/type1.html

Comment: We also have a few questions related to this issue (bitmap fonts) on this site.  For example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291/86 seems relevant.  You'll find more if you search for `bitmap fonts`.

Comment: Also note that there appears to be a newer version `aiaa-tc.cls` since 2004 which uses vector fonts by default (`\documentclass{aiaa-tc}`). Documentation: http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/aiaa/aiaa.pdf

Comment: @HarroldCavendish: I believe this could be an answer.

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov: I shall wait for the OP's word before writing and answer because I am a little unsure whether the `aiaa-tc` class is what he is looking for – it creates a single column article, while the `aiaa` a two column one. Most recent journal articles downloaded from the AIAA website feature a two column layout and the new class is most probably intended only for technical conference papers. From what I have read, it appears that `aiaa.cls` was used only for simulating journal appearance. The only official template that the AIAA provides is called “AIAA Meeting Papers Template”.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After downloading the LaTeX template containing[`aiaa.cls`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/aiaa/pre2004/aiaa.pdf)from the [AIAA official website](http://www.aiaa.org/content.cfm?pageid=396) and installing a couple of obsolete packages, most importantly `dropping`, I have found that the output uses vector Type 1 fonts.

The solution is therefore, as suggested by Stefan Kottwitz, in [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically/1293#1293) to install the `cm-super` package.

However, the `aiaa.cls` seems to be obsolete, which is indicated even by its placement in a folder named `pre2004`. Therefore I recommend using[`aiaa-tc.cls`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/aiaa/aiaa.pdf)when possible.

Comment: And someone should contact the AIAA to update their LaTeX class. LaTeX really isn't rocket science. :-)

Comment: I had some issues with aiaa-tc.cls....
Therefore I think I will continue with aiaa.cls for the present...
The problem with cm-super is that Latex is not able to find it. 
Just installed it using the package-manager but still it doesn't recognize cm-super. :(

Comment: @ShashankSawant Might be a silly question, but did it or you run `updmap-sys`?

Comment: @HarroldCavendish How to run updmap-sys? Thanks for your previous advice! :)

Comment: You could also use Latin Modern, same typeface, but with updated kerning and support for more languages.

Comment: The way I think the problem was solved was after re-installing cm-super package(using MikTex package manager). Still in the main file, the following code gives me an error:
    \usepackage{cm-super}
saying cm-super.sty not found. 

Regardless, the problem is solved.