# How to run updmap-sys after installing cm-super?

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex

My original question was:
[How to improve rendering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/how-to-improve-rendering)

The answer that seems suitable to my cause is to install `cm-super`. I did that (using package manager [winxp 32 bit, MikTex installation 2.9 recently updated]). But still the command

```
\usepackage{cm-super}
```

yields an error.

User H Cavendish suggested to run `updmap-sys`, but I am not sure about how to do that on WinXP.

2011 November 04 edit:
I made it sure that I have installed 'cm-super' - but still get the same error:
[image: cm-super error]

I have also tried updating the file name databases - but no avail.

Comment: The [`cm-super` INSTALL](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super/INSTALL) is pretty clear on how to install [`cm-super`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super). Did you follow the instructions for MiKTeX correctly?

Comment: My apologies for not answering your question in the previous topic. I did not notice it and generally lack free time these days.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish  np np...
Because of your help I could solve the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Miktex doesn't know `updmap-sys`. The miktex version of this command is `updmap --admin` or `initexmf --admin --mkmaps`. But miktex does run this command at install so if it didn't worked for you probably have a multi-user installation and a user map file. In this case you should run `updmap` as user (without the `--admin` part.) To do this open a command prompt and type `updmap` and then hit enter. (The command prompt window can be opened by entering "cmd" (without quotes) into Start-Run or through Start-All Programs-Accessories.)

Comment: This was so helpful for me, I coudn't find out why it didn't work for me, I had the package install and everything, but I didn't think this could be due to a multi-user installation! Thank a lot

Answer (score 4):

Under miktex, you should open the "MiKTeX Settings" program and click on the "Refresh FNDB" button (located under the "General" tab). This should update the MiKTeX's file name database.

Comment: I am not sure which is the answer that helped, Ulrike's or yours, but somehow your answer seems more likely. Ulrike's answer is more informative and I think I need to dig deeper.