# Problem with concmath package

Tags: fonts, packages

I'm trying to use the concmath package (along with T1 fontec package) but the resulting text looks jagged and not vector-like, but I have seen some documents using this font that look vector-like.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{concmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Let me guess: you're running MiKTeX on Windows. The problem is longstanding: you need a working installation of the CM-Super fonts. See the accepted answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/ and Ulrike Fischer's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/

Comment: @egreg: for the text one naturally needs a proper installation of cm-super but imho there is no type1 version of the math fonts. Or do you get them with e.g. `$f(x)=\int y$`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There is no Type1 version of the Concrete math fonts. But one can use `eulervm`