# Some troubles with the font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-encodings

I've just noticed, that after rendering if I zoom the text then it look like a low quality text (look at the screen). I've heard that I can install `cm-super` package. I put `\usepackage{cm-super}` to the preamble but get an error "cm-super.sty not found". Before If I didn't have any package latex suggested me to install it right in the latex so I didn't have to visit any websites or something. Am I supposed to install it manually? 
Anyway, how can I solve the problem? 
I have two files in my project: latex file and .sty file. Here's how the preambles look:

1. In the main file:

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
   \usepackage{Lections_style}
   ```

   2. In the lections style:

      ```
        \RequirePackage{amsfonts}
        \RequirePackage{amsmath}
        \RequirePackage{amssymb}
        \RequirePackage{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage{babel,blindtext}
        \RequirePackage{subfigure}
        \RequirePackage{hyperref}
        \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
        \RequirePackage{cite}
        \RequirePackage{amsthm}
        \RequirePackage{xparse}
        \RequirePackage{mathabx}
        \RequirePackage{array}
        \RequirePackage{tabularx}
        \RequirePackage{multirow}
        \RequirePackage{makecell}
      ```

There're already 55 pages typed so I would be very glad if there's any solution without a lot of pain. Thank you and sorry for my English.

I've been asked to give a MWE, so here it is:

```
   \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article} 
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[english, russian]{babel} 
    \begin{document} Проверка текста. 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly, you don't have a cyrillic font in `true type` or `type 1` format that pdflatex is aware of. As for `mathabx`, do you have `mathabx-type1` installed?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi what is MWE, sorry?

Comment: @Bernard I didn't understand you. Could you explain?

Comment: That is a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I've just updated it to the main post, watch

Comment: What is the cyrillic font you use? I suppose it is a true type font (extension: `.ttf`) or  Postscript type 1 (extension: `.pfb`). The problem is that `pdflatex` has to know where to find them, otherwise it will substitute `bitmap`fonts, hence the pixellisation if zoomed. This is done through a `.map` file.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, but where can I check what you wrote? I'm not a professional user of latex, so I would like to get more info about where I can find it

Comment: There is no `cm-super` LaTeX package. Are you using MiKTeX, by chance?

Comment: @egreg yes, I am

Comment: Ensure you have installed the MiKTeX package `mathabx-type1` and run `initexmf` as suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33635/4427)

Comment: @egreg Should I install the package manually? Bc my latex said that the style file not found. What should I run, how?

Comment: @MGMKLML I meant http://miktex.org/packages/mathabx-type1 Install it with the MiKTeX wizard. It's a package in the sense of MiKTeX, not a LaTeX package, just like `cm-super`.

Comment: @egreg If I have already installed the miktex, how can I install the package without deleting miktex and installing again?

Comment: @egreg I've tried to go there and install from there, but I get what is on the screen below 
[here it is](http://s019.radikal.ru/i638/1508/9e/801bf0bc1512.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

From the `start menu` launch `MiKTeX Package Manager`, select `mathabx-type1`, right-click on the selection and select `install`. base.

To install `cm-super`, do the same from MPM.

Finally  run from the command-line: `updmap --verbose` to update the type 1 fonts database.

[image]

*Added*: I forgot this (important)  detail: for the `mathabx` fonts to be displayed with their type 1 versions, as there is no `.fd` file, add this to your preamble:

```
 \DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
 <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12
 }{}
```

and do the same for `mathb` and `mathx` if you want to use them.