# PK font rtxmi could not be created

Tags: fonts, errors

I am trying to compile an article for an AIP (physics) journal using the follow MWE:

```
\documentclass[aip,jcp, floatfix, preprint, 12pt, noshowpacs, superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphics}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
linkcolor={red!50!black},
citecolor={blue!50!black},
urlcolor={blue!80!black}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
this gives errors
\title[Al$_{2}$O$_{3}$ ceramic]{alumina ceramic}
\bibliography{mybib}
    \end{document}
```

__> when compiling I get the following error:

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:

"The rtxmi source file could not be found."

I followed several other font issue queries including [Problems with fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152721/problems-with-fonts) and thought reinstalled --> updated Miktex twice as both admin and user following --> https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html#fndb
I also  preformed the suggested maintenance using the MikTek Maintenance --> Settings --> refresh FNDB and update all format files Update Formats

And still no luck... I don't know if this an actual error with the font or some other issue with re-installation and updating the program.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Run updmap on a command line.

Comment: Ulrike - I opened and ran the updmap in the cmd from start as you describe "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/how-to-run-updmap-sys-after-installing-cm-super" but I still get the same error: Runaway argument?
width=0.8\textwidth ]{xxx.jpg} \caption [Raw Bri\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par

Comment: Or @UlrikeFischer will pint Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: How can you say that `Runaway argument?` is the **same** error as `miktex-makemf did not succeed`? You obviously have a new error related to one of your figures (which isn't in your MWE above). So make a new question.