# miktex-makepk failed to process HieroA

Tags: miktex2.9, hieroglf

I tried to install Hierogryph with miktex 2.9, following the instuction and the suggestion of [PK font rtxmi could not be created](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386430/pk-font-rtxmi-could-not-be-created). But I still got this error( repeatedly):

```
> miktex-makepk - this process (3456) started by 'yap' with 
>      command line: miktex-makepk --verbose HieroA 864 600 
>      magstep(2.0) ljfour 2020-05-03 15:39:58,076+0200 INFO makepk - 
>      Trying to make PK font HieroA at 864 DPI... 2020-05-03   
>       5:39:58,096+0200 INFO makepk - Running miktex-makemf.exe...  
>       2020-05-03 15:39:58,096+0200 INFO makepk - running: miktex-
>       makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-
>       maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose HieroA 
>       2020-05-03 15:39:58,164+0200 INFO miktex-makepk.core - start 
>      process: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-
>      disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose HieroA 
>      2020-05-03 15:39:58,548+0200 INFO makepk - Running miktex- 
>      ttf2pk.exe... 2020-05-03 15:39:58,548+0200 INFO makepk - 
>      running:miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-
>      disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -q -t HieroA 
>      2020-05-03 15:39:58,558+0200 INFO miktex-makepk.core - start 
>     process: miktex-ttf2pk.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-
>     disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -q -t HieroA 
>     2020-05-03 15:39:59,061+0200 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font
>      HieroA could not be created.
```

I have installed HieroTex 3.5 and HierType 3.1.4
Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens if you add `\pdfmapline{=HieroA HieroA <HieroA.pfa}` to your document?

Comment: thanks. it says you cannot use # in horizontal mode. Probably I put your insdtruction in the wrong place.( before begin {document}. It says also that \@ input{egypto.sty.aux} No file egypto.sty.tex