# Longtable struggle

Tags: lists, longtable

I had been struggling with this table for two weeks..
I prepared a sort of MWE but I had to leave the great part of my work because is part of the question and because I'm a novice in LaTeX.

I'm trying to make a long table using LaTeX. The results that I have since obtained are awful ..

1. the table splits in an incomprehensible way.. there is still a lot of space in the page but it goes in the next page, it really drives me crazy how a two pages table in Word becomes a 5 pages table in LaTeX;
2. even if I used \clearpage and \afterpage the header on the page following the first one is again there;
3. if you see the table in word that I am trying to convert in the first three rows is different from the one I tried to convert using LaTeX, I was not able to reproduce it. I tried to use \multicol command but the column didn't stop and ended out of the page on the right;
4. I tried to modify the margins to gain a more large table but with no results..

May I have your help?

```
\documentclass\[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage\[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage\[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage\[italian,english]{babel} 
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol} %random text
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage\[italian]{varioref} 
\usepackage{palatino,lettrine} %per fare le lettere grandi iniziali
\usepackage{paralist}%to itemize with i ii and letters a) b) c)
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array,supertabular,multirow,longtable}%for tabular ad big tables
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}%booktabs is to set midrule and toprule
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{array}
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}%setspace package allows more fine-grained control over line spacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nameref}%to get the name of the chap-sec-paragh in references
\usepackage{bbding}%to define special caracters i.e. crosses for tables
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage\[labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=it,labelsep=period\]{caption}% to define the caption label
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture} 
\usepackage\[normalem]{ulem} % to strikethrough sentences
\usepackage{enumitem}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PAGE LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\setlrmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{0.9} 
\setulmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{*} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\checkandfixthelayout 
\setlength{\parindent}{10 mm} 
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{14pt plus 12pt minus 0.1pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADING STYLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{verville}{
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\chapnamefont}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\chapnumfont\hfill\thechapter\\\vspace*{-.3cm}\hrulefill\vspace*{5cm}\\}
}

\newcommand\TextForDocSignature{%
  \parbox\[t\]{\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \footnotesize\itshape
   \begin{tiny}  Bravo, Alpha, Delta, Gamma \\ "La prova della storia della storia"\\
 \end{tiny}    
  }%
}
\newcommand\DocSignature{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
    \put(\spinemargin,1.2cm){\TextForDocSignature}%
    \else%
    \put(\foremargin,1cm){\TextForDocSignature}%
    \fi%
  }%
}

\strictpagecheck
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother
\selectlanguage{italian}



\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                 CONTENT CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\chapterstyle{thesis} 
\pagestyle{Ruled} 
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{10.5pt}\selectfont} 
\footmarkstyle{\hfill\textsuperscript{#1} }
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0.6cm}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-0.6cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{.65\onelineskip}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1.6\onelineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{10 mm} 




\chapter{Gli atti di polizia giudiziaria  }

\lipsum\[1\]
\section{secondi atti}

\lipsum\[1\]


\clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)

\afterpage{%



%-------------THE TABLE THAT I STRUGGLING ON..---------------------------

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{longtable}{ m{2.5cm} | m{12.5cm} }
\caption{Use case detail}\label{chap3:tab1}\\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}\\\[12pt\]
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot


% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\multicolumn{2}{c}{SCHEDE DESCRITTIVE - CODICE PENALE}\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARTICOLO & 423 bis\\
%\hline
REATO & Incendio boschivo doloso o colposo \\
\hline


\multicolumn{2}{c}{N. SCHEDA 3}\\


% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cosa stabilisce il codice penale &
Art. 423-bis. (Incendio boschivo)\newline
Chiunque cagiona un incendio su boschi, selve o foreste ovvero su vivai forestali destinati al rimboschimento, propri o altrui, è punito con la reclusione da quattro a dieci anni. 
Se l'incendio di cui al primo comma è cagionato per colpa, la pena è della reclusione da uno a cinque anni. 
Le pene previste dal primo e dal secondo comma sono aumentate se dall'incendio deriva pericolo per edifici o danno su aree protette. 
Le pene previste dal primo e dal secondo comma sono aumentate della metà, se dall'incendio deriva un danno grave, esteso e persistente all'ambiente\\
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Definizione incendio boschivo &\mbox{}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}
\item L. 21 novembre 2000, n. 353 - Legge-quadro in materia di incendi boschivi.
Art. 2. - (Definizione) - Comma 1. 
Per incendio boschivo si intende un fuoco con suscettività a espandersi su aree boscate, cespugliate o arborate, comprese eventuali strutture e infrastrutture antropizzate poste all'interno delle predette aree, oppure su terreni coltivati o incolti e pascoli limitrofi a dette aree.

\item D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34 - Testo unico in materia di foreste e filiere forestali
Art. 3 – (Definizioni) - Comma 1. 
I termini bosco, foresta e selva sono equiparati.
Art. 3. (Definizioni) - Comma 3. 
Per le materie di competenza esclusiva dello Stato \footnote{Tra le materie di esclusiva competenza dello Stato rientra senz’altro l’applicazione della legge penale}, sono definite bosco le superfici coperte da vegetazione forestale arborea, associata o meno a quella arbustiva, di origine naturale o artificiale in qualsiasi stadio di sviluppo ed evoluzione, con estensione non inferiore ai 2.000 metri quadri, larghezza media non inferiore a 20 metri e con copertura arborea forestale maggiore del 20 per cento. 
\item Cass. Pen., III, n. 28928 del 20/07/2011 – Pres. Ferrua – Rel. Mulliri – Ric. Sardu: Per bosco e macchia mediterranea, … , si intende anche quella caratterizzata dalla assenza di alberi di alto fusto.
\end{enumerate}\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Elemento oggettivo del reato & Il Codice penale tratta di un incendio “su boschi, selve o foreste ovvero su vivai forestali destinati al rimboschimento, propri o altrui”.
La legge descrive l’incendio boschivo come un incendio di vegetazione le cui fiamme si possono espandere in maniera tale da poter raggiungere (o aver già raggiunto) un bosco o una zona coperta d’arbusti, boscaglia o macchia mediterranea come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3).
Per altri incendi di vegetazione si procede per gli artt. 423 – 449 c.p.\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Soggetto\newline attivo & Chiunque può essere indagato per il reato di incendio boschivo\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Elemento soggettivo &\mbox{}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Comma 1: dolo – in questo caso vi può essere il tentato delitto: occorre procedere ai sensi dell’art. 423 bis c.p.  se l’incendiario (o il piromane ) provoca un incendio di vegetazione (STAT RI WEB: Cod. 301 – incendio di bosco, sterpaglia colture) le cui fiamme possono espandersi in maniera tale da poter raggiungere (o aver già raggiunto) un bosco oppure una zona coperta da arbusti (sterpaglia), boscaglia o macchia mediterranea. 
\item Comma 2 – colpa - in questo caso, si procede per incendio boschivo solo quando l’incendio ha interessato effettivamente un bosco, come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3)\footnote{Si sottolinea la fondamentale distinzione tra “piromane” ed “incendiario” (cfr. “Linee guida attività investigativa del corpo nazionale vigili del fuoco sugli incendi boschivi e territoriali” emanate dal CNVVF).
Piromane = persona sofferente di una patologia clinica chiamata piromanìa, che consiste nell’ impulso ossessivo a provocare incendi. La piromania clinica è un’intensa ossessione verso il fuoco, un disturbo del controllo degli impulsi, una dipendenza, che spinge le persone ad appiccare fuochi. Il piromane non si rende conto della gravità del suo comportamento, anzi, spesso si mescola ai soccorritori, si ferma a osservare le fiamme, traendone piacere. Quindi il piromane agisce per motivi psicopatologici.
Incendiario = persona che provoca un incendio consapevolmente, per motivi razionali e per interessi personali e materiali. Secondo l’FBI, le motivazioni criminali prevalenti sono: per vandalismo, per vendetta, per profitto, per eccitazione, per sviare le indagini su un altro reato, per distruggere prove. E’ ormai invalso l’uso comune, soprattutto sui mezzi di informazione e di comunicazione, di impiegare indifferentemente i due termini come sinonimi, per indicare il responsabile di un incendio boschivo. In realtà la P.G. deve distinguere attentamente le due fattispecie, in quanto, come detto, la piromania è una “malattia”, quindi il piromane agisce con modalità e con motivazioni assai diverse da un incendiario.
}
\end{enumerate}
Si noti che l'incendio boschivo colposo (art. 423 bis comma 2 c.p.) e l'incendio colposo (art. 423 e 449 c.p.) sono puniti entrambi con pene da 1 a 5 anni quindi l’art. 423 bis c.p. assume particolare valenza nel caso di azioni dolose (incendiari o piromani).

\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
Principali aspetti procedurali (connessi anche alla pena stabilita)& Si procede d’ufficio. Competenza: Tribunale. \mbox{}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Comma 1: dolo
    \begin{itemize}
     \item Maggiorenni: 
       \begin{itemize}
       \item arresto obbligatorio in flagranza di reato (art. 380 c.p.p.);
       \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
       \end{itemize}
    \item Minori: 
       \begin{itemize}
       \item arresto facoltativo in flagranza di reato (D.P.R. 448/1988, art. 16 c. 1 e c.3 e art. 23);
       \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
     \end{itemize}
     \end{itemize}
\item Comma 2: colpa 
\begin{itemize}
\item Maggiorenni: 
\begin{itemize}
\item arresto facoltativo in flagranza di reato (art. 381 c.p.p.);
\item fermo non consentito (art. 384 c.p.);
\end{itemize}
\item Minori(D.P.R. 448/1988):
\begin{itemize}
\item arresto non consentito (D.P.R. 448/1988, art. 16 c. 1 e c.3 e 23);
\item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
\end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Altre note ed informazioni di rilievo&Di norma, sui reati di incendio boschivo procede, per specifica competenza (D.M. Interno 15/08/2017 recante la “ Direttiva sui comparti di specialità delle Forze di Polizia e sulla razionalizzazione dei presidi di polizia ”), l’Arma dei Carabinieri, alla quale occorre fornire ogni utile contributo informativo ed operativo (cfr. la nota DCPREV n. 10853 del 4-08-2017 ed il Protocollo di Intesa tra il Comandante dell'Arma dei Carabinieri e il Capo del Dipartimento dei Vigili del Fuoco sottoscritto il 5 aprile 2017).\\
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hline
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Elementi da evidenziare nei rapporti d'intervento& \mbox{}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}
\item se le fiamme hanno interessato o potevano sicuramente raggiungere, senza l’intervento VVF, un bosco o una zona coperta d’arbusti, boscaglia o macchia mediterranea come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3);
\item se si è trattato di un incendio (difficile spegnimento) o principio d’incendio/fuoco riferendosi all’area bruciata, alle squadre impegnate ed al tempo necessario per lo spegnimento;
\item se le presumibili cause sono dolose o colpose ed in base a quali indizi. 
\end{enumerate}




\end{longtable}
}

\restoregeometry     %


\clearpage




\lipsum\[1\]



\end{document}
```

the table I'm trying to convert

[image]

\lipsum[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq4V2.png)

Update. After the suggestion given by Ulrike Fischer, I transformed the long table into a list. Do you think is comprehensible or should I go back to the table? Thank you again for your help

```
\begin{spacing}{1.3}

\begin{table}[h!]

    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  c  r   }
    ARTICOLO &  REATO  &    N. SCHEDA\\
    423 bis  & Incendio boschivo & 3\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
     \vspace{-1cm}

    \begin{description}[itemsep=0.1cm,  style=multiline,leftmargin=3 cm,font=\normalfont]
       \item[Cosa stabilisce il codice penale]  
       Art. 423-bis. (Incendio boschivo). 
    Chiunque cagiona un incendio su boschi, selve o foreste ovvero su vivai forestali destinati al rimboschimento, propri o altrui, è punito con la reclusione da quattro a dieci anni. 
    Se l'incendio di cui al primo comma è cagionato per colpa, la pena è della reclusione da uno a cinque anni. 
    Le pene previste dal primo e dal secondo comma sono aumentate se dall'incendio deriva pericolo per edifici o danno su aree protette. 
    Le pene previste dal primo e dal secondo comma sono aumentate della metà, se dall'incendio deriva un danno grave, esteso e persistente all'ambiente

    \item[Definizione incendio boschivo]  
    \begin{compactenum}[i)]
    \item L. 21 novembre 2000, n. 353 - Legge-quadro in materia di incendi boschivi.
    Art. 2. - (Definizione) - Comma 1. 
    Per incendio boschivo si intende un fuoco con suscettività a espandersi su aree boscate, cespugliate o arborate, comprese eventuali strutture e infrastrutture antropizzate poste all'interno delle predette aree, oppure su terreni coltivati o incolti e pascoli limitrofi a dette aree;
    \item D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34 - Testo unico in materia di foreste e filiere forestali Art. 3 – (Definizioni) - Comma 1. 
    I termini bosco, foresta e selva sono equiparati.
    Art. 3. (Definizioni) - Comma 3. 
    Per le materie di competenza esclusiva dello Stato \footnote{Tra le materie di esclusiva competenza dello Stato rientra senz’altro l’applicazione della legge penale.} , sono definite bosco le superfici coperte da vegetazione forestale arborea, associata o meno a quella arbustiva, di origine naturale
     o artificiale in qualsiasi stadio di sviluppo ed evoluzione, con estensione non inferiore ai 2.000 metri quadri, larghezza media non inferiore a 20 metri e con copertura arborea forestale maggiore del 20 per cento.
    \item \textbf{D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34 - Testo unico in materia di foreste e filiere forestali}\\  
    Art. 3 – (Definizioni) - Comma 1. 
    I termini bosco, foresta e selva sono equiparati.
    Art. 3. (Definizioni) - Comma 3. 
    Per le materie di competenza esclusiva dello Stato , sono definite bosco le superfici coperte da vegetazione forestale arborea, associata o meno a quella arbustiva, di origine naturale
     o artificiale in qualsiasi stadio di sviluppo ed evoluzione, con estensione non inferiore ai 2.000 metri quadri, larghezza media non inferiore a 20 metri e con copertura arborea forestale maggiore del 20 per cento. 
    \item \textbf{Cass. Pen., III, n. 28928 del 20/07/2011 – Pres. Ferrua – Rel. Mulliri – Ric. Sardu:}\\ Per bosco e macchia mediterranea, … , si intende anche quella caratterizzata dalla assenza di alberi di alto fusto.
    \end{compactenum}
    \item[Elemento oggettivo del reato] Il Codice penale tratta di un incendio “su boschi, selve o foreste ovvero su vivai forestali destinati al rimboschimento, propri o altrui”.
    La legge descrive l'incendio boschivo come un incendio di vegetazione le cui fiamme si possono espandere in maniera tale da poter raggiungere (o aver già raggiunto) un bosco o una zona coperta d’arbusti, boscaglia o macchia mediterranea come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3).
    Per altri incendi di vegetazione si procede per gli artt. 423 – 449 c.p
    \item[Soggetto attivo]Chiunque può essere indagato per il reato di incendio boschivo
    \item[Elemento soggettivo]
    \begin{compactenum}[i)]
    \item Comma 1: dolo – in questo caso vi può essere il tentato delitto: occorre procedere ai sensi dell’art. 423 bis c.p.  se l’incendiario (o il piromane ) provoca un incendio di vegetazione (STAT RI WEB: Cod. 301 – incendio di bosco, sterpaglia colture) le cui fiamme possono espandersi in maniera tale da poter raggiungere (o aver già raggiunto) un bosco oppure una zona coperta da arbusti (sterpaglia), boscaglia o macchia mediterranea.
    \item Comma 2 – colpa - in questo caso, si procede per incendio boschivo solo quando l’incendio ha interessato effettivamente un bosco, come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3)\footnote{Si sottolinea la fondamentale distinzione tra “piromane” ed “incendiario” (cfr. “Linee guida attività investigativa del corpo nazionale vigili del fuoco sugli incendi boschivi e territoriali” emanate dal CNVVF).
    Piromane = persona sofferente di una patologia clinica chiamata piromanìa, che consiste nell’ impulso ossessivo a provocare incendi. La piromania clinica è un’intensa ossessione verso il fuoco, un disturbo del controllo degli impulsi una dipendenza, che spinge le persone ad appiccare fuochi. Il piromane non si rende conto della gravità del suo comportamento, anzi, spesso si mescola ai soccorritori, si ferma a osservare le fiamme, traendone piacere. Quindi il piromane agisce per motivi psicopatologici.
    Incendiario = persona che provoca un incendio consapevolmente, per motivi razionali e per interessi personali e materiali. Secondo l’FBI, le motivazioni criminali prevalenti sono: per vandalismo, per vendetta, per profitto, per eccitazione, per sviare le indagini su un altro reato, per distruggere prove. E’ ormai invalso l’uso comune, soprattutto sui mezzi di informazione e di comunicazione, di impiegare indifferentemente i due termini come sinonimi, per indicare il responsabile di un incendio boschivo. In realtà la P.G. deve distinguere attentamente le due fattispecie, in quanto, come detto, la piromania è una “malattia”, quindi il piromane agisce con modalità e con motivazioni assai diverse da un incendiario.} . 
    Si noti che l’incendio boschivo colposo (art. 423 bis comma 2 c.p.) e l’incendio colposo (art. 423 e 449 c.p.) sono puniti entrambi con pene da 1 a 5 anni quindi l’art. 423 bis c.p. assume particolare valenza nel caso di azioni dolose (incendiari o piromani).
    \end{compactenum}
    \item[Principali aspetti procedurali (connessi anche alla pena stabilita)]
    Si procede d’ufficio. Competenza: Tribunale. 
    \begin{compactenum}[i)]
    \item Comma 1: dolo
        \begin{itemize}
         \item Maggiorenni: 
           \begin{itemize}
           \item arresto obbligatorio in flagranza di reato (art. 380 c.p.p.);
           \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
           \end{itemize}
        \item Minori: 
           \begin{itemize}
           \item arresto facoltativo in flagranza di reato (D.P.R. 448/1988, art. 16 c. 1 e c.3 e art. 23);
           \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
         \end{itemize}
         \end{itemize}
    \item Comma 2: colpa 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Maggiorenni: 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item arresto facoltativo in flagranza di reato (art. 381 c.p.p.);
    \item fermo non consentito (art. 384 c.p.);
    \end{itemize}
    \item Minori(D.P.R. 448/1988):
    \begin{itemize}
    \item arresto non consentito (D.P.R. 448/1988, art. 16 c. 1 e c.3 e 23);
    \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{compactenum}
    \item[Altre note ed informazioni di rilievo] Di norma, sui reati di incendio boschivo procede, per specifica competenza (D.M. Interno 15/08/2017 recante la “ Direttiva sui comparti di specialità delle Forze di Polizia e sulla razionalizzazione dei presidi di polizia ”), l’Arma dei Carabinieri, alla quale occorre fornire ogni utile contributo informativo ed operativo (cfr. la nota DCPREV n. 10853 del 4-08-2017 ed il Protocollo di Intesa tra il Comandante dell'Arma dei Carabinieri e il Capo del Dipartimento dei Vigili del Fuoco sottoscritto il 5 aprile 2017).  
    \item[Elementi da evidenziare nei rapporti d’intervento]Ai fini di PG il ROS dovrà riportare ed evidenziare nel rapporto d’intervento soprattutto i seguenti elementi:
    \begin{compactenum}[i)]
    \item se le fiamme hanno interessato o potevano sicuramente raggiungere, senza l’intervento VVF, un bosco o una zona coperta d’arbusti, boscaglia o macchia mediterranea come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3);
    \item se si è trattato di un incendio (difficile spegnimento) o principio d’incendio/fuoco riferendosi all’area bruciata, alle squadre impegnate ed al tempo necessario per lo spegnimento;
    \item se le presumibili cause sono dolose o colpose ed in base a quali indizi. 
    \end{compactenum}
      \end{description}
     \end{spacing}
```

[image: first page of the table I'm trying to convert in LaTeX]

Comment: I fixed up some of your markdown (use `1.` for lists and `{}` button to indent by four spaces for code,. Your example is still incomplete it includes lots of packages irrelevant to this question which you should remove but isn't a complete document (no `\end{document}` for example so we can not run it to see the problem.

Comment: Note that longtable can only break the page between rows, and you have very large items (nested lists) within the row. Don't use `\afterpage` unless everything else is working and you really need to make some final adjustments. (and after `\clearpage` where you have it it does not do anything useful at all.)

Comment: `\documentclass\[12pt,a4paper\]{memoir} `, `\usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc} ` etc are wrong, correct is `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} `, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. please correct at all options of loaded packages.

Comment: Why do you use `\[` and `\]` instead of `[` and `]` (12 instances each)?

Comment: This type of layout should normally better be done without a tabular. Lists + marginnotes  + and some tikz or tcolorbox for the lines are better options.

Comment: Excuse me is my MWE is too long but I wanted to show the problems that I'm facing.. About the comment of Ulrike can you explain me better please I'm not so good and smart in LaTeX

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

I gather that there are a quite a few issues you wish to fix with the `longtable`. Assuming you wish to stick with the `longtable` setup, I suggest you employ the machinery of the `enumitem` package -- which is already loaded in the preamble of your document -- to create compact `enumerate`- and `itemize`-like environments. E.g.,

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*.,
         nosep, leftmargin=*,
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
         after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\textbullet,
         nosep, leftmargin=*,
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
         after=\end{minipage}}
\setlist[mylist,2]{label={--},
         nosep, leftmargin=*,
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\hsize},
         after=\end{minipage}}
```

Then, inside the `longtable` environment, replace all instances of `{enumerate}` with `{myenum}`. Furthermore, replace all instances of  `{itemize}` with `{mylist}`. For sure, using the more compact enumerate and itemize environments makes the `longtable` fit on just 3 pages. I trust that's a significant improvement.

---

Here's the revised code. Note that I've introduced a few paragraph breaks  here and there. If this goes again Italian Legalese typesetting conventions, feel free to remove the paragraph breaks. :-)

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol} %random text
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % "palatino" package is obsolete
\usepackage{lettrine} %per fare le lettere grandi iniziali
\usepackage{paralist}%to itemize with i ii and letters a) b) c)
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array,supertabular,multirow,longtable}%for tabular ad big tables
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}%booktabs is to set midrule and toprule
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{array}
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}%setspace package allows more fine-grained control over line spacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nameref}%to get the name of the chap-sec-paragh in references
\usepackage{bbding}%to define special caracters i.e. crosses for tables
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=it,%
    labelsep=period]{caption}% to define the caption label
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % to strikethrough sentences

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*.,
         nosep, leftmargin=*,
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
         after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\textbullet,
         nosep, leftmargin=*,
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
         after=\end{minipage}}
\setlist[mylist,2]{label={--},
         nosep, leftmargin=*,
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\hsize},
         after=\end{minipage}}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\frenchspacing

%-------------------------
%   PAGE LAYOUT
%-------------------------

\setlrmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{0.9}
\setulmarginsandblock{37.125mm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\parindent}{10 mm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{14pt plus 12pt minus 0.1pt}

%-------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADING STYLE
%-------------------------

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{verville}{
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\chapnamefont}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\chapnumfont\hfill\thechapter\\\vspace*{-.3cm}\hrulefill\vspace*{5cm}\\}
}

\newcommand\TextForDocSignature{%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \footnotesize\itshape
   \begin{tiny}  Bravo, Alpha, Delta, Gamma \\ "La prova della storia della storia"\\
 \end{tiny}
  }%
}
\newcommand\DocSignature{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
    \put(\spinemargin,1.2cm){\TextForDocSignature}%
    \else%
    \put(\foremargin,1cm){\TextForDocSignature}%
    \fi%
  }%
}

\strictpagecheck
%-----------------------
\makeatother
\selectlanguage{italian}



\begin{document}

%----------------------------------
%              CONTENT CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\chapterstyle{thesis}
\pagestyle{Ruled}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{10.5pt}\selectfont}
\footmarkstyle{\hfill\textsuperscript{#1} }
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0.6cm}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-0.6cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{.65\onelineskip}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1.6\onelineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{10 mm}




\chapter{Gli atti di polizia giudiziaria  }
\lipsum[1]

\section{secondi atti}

%\clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)

\afterpage{%



%----- THE TABLE THAT I STRUGGLE WITH ----------
\begingroup % <-- new
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\raggedright}m{2.5cm} | 
                      m{12.5cm} @{}}

\caption{Use case detail}
\label{chap3:tab1}\\
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}\\[1\baselineskip]
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot


%
\multicolumn{2}{c}{SCHEDE DESCRITTIVE - CODICE PENALE}\\
%
\hline
%
ARTICOLO & 423 bis\\
%\hline

REATO & Incendio boschivo doloso o colposo \\
\hline


\multicolumn{2}{c}{N. SCHEDA 3}\\


%
\hline
%
Cosa stabilisce il codice penale &
Art. 423-bis. (Incendio boschivo)\newline
Chiunque cagiona un incendio su boschi, selve o foreste ovvero su vivai forestali destinati al rimboschimento, propri o altrui, è punito con la reclusione da quattro a dieci anni. Se l'incendio di cui al primo comma è cagionato per colpa, la pena è della reclusione da uno a cinque anni. Le pene previste dal primo e dal secondo comma sono aumentate se dall'incendio deriva pericolo per edifici o danno su aree protette. Le pene previste dal primo e dal secondo comma sono aumentate della metà, se dall'incendio deriva un danno grave, esteso e persistente all'ambiente\\
\hline
%
Definizione incendio boschivo &

\begin{myenum}
\item L. 21 novembre 2000, n. 353 - Legge-quadro in materia di incendi boschivi.

Art. 2. – (Definizione) - Comma 1.
Per incendio boschivo si intende un fuoco con suscettività a espandersi su aree boscate, cespugliate o arborate, comprese eventuali strutture e infrastrutture antropizzate poste all'interno delle predette aree, oppure su terreni coltivati o incolti e pascoli limitrofi a dette aree.

\item D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34 - Testo unico in materia di foreste e filiere forestali

Art. 3. – (Definizioni) - Comma 1.
I termini bosco, foresta e selva sono equiparati.

Art. 3. – (Definizioni) - Comma 3.
Per le materie di competenza esclusiva dello Stato \footnote{Tra le materie di esclusiva competenza dello Stato rientra senz’altro l’applicazione della legge penale}, sono definite bosco le superfici coperte da vegetazione forestale arborea, associata o meno a quella arbustiva, di origine naturale o artificiale in qualsiasi stadio di sviluppo ed evoluzione, con estensione non inferiore ai 2.000 metri quadri, larghezza media non inferiore a 20~metri e con copertura arborea forestale maggiore del 20 per~cento.

\item Cass. Pen., III, n. 28928 del 20/07/2011 – Pres. Ferrua – Rel. Mulliri – Ric. Sardu: Per bosco e macchia mediterranea, … , si intende anche quella caratterizzata dalla assenza di alberi di alto fusto.
\end{myenum}\\
%
\hline
%
Elemento oggettivo del reato & Il Codice penale tratta di un incendio “su boschi, selve o foreste ovvero su vivai forestali destinati al rimboschimento, propri o altrui”.
La legge descrive l’incendio boschivo come un incendio di vegetazione le cui fiamme si possono espandere in maniera tale da poter raggiungere (o aver già raggiunto) un bosco o una zona coperta d’arbusti, boscaglia o macchia mediterranea come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n.~34, art.~3 comma~3).
Per altri incendi di vegetazione si procede per gli artt. 423 – 449 c.p.\\
%
\hline
%
Soggetto\newline attivo & Chiunque può essere indagato per il reato di incendio boschivo\\
%
\hline
%
Elemento soggettivo &

\begin{myenum}
\item Comma 1: dolo – in questo caso vi può essere il tentato delitto: occorre procedere ai sensi dell’art. 423 bis c.p.  se l’incendiario (o il piromane ) provoca un incendio di vegetazione (STAT RI WEB: Cod. 301 – incendio di bosco, sterpaglia colture) le cui fiamme possono espandersi in maniera tale da poter raggiungere (o aver già raggiunto) un bosco oppure una zona coperta da arbusti (sterpaglia), boscaglia o macchia mediterranea.

\item Comma 2 – colpa - in questo caso, si procede per incendio boschivo solo quando l’incendio ha interessato effettivamente un bosco, come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3~aprile 2018, n.~34, art.~3 comma~3)%
    \footnote{Si sottolinea la fondamentale distinzione tra “piromane” ed “incendiario” (cfr. “Linee guida attività investigativa del corpo nazionale vigili del fuoco sugli incendi boschivi e territoriali” emanate dal CNVVF).

Piromane = persona sofferente di una patologia clinica chiamata piromanìa, che consiste nell’ impulso ossessivo a provocare incendi. La piromania clinica è un’intensa ossessione verso il fuoco, un disturbo del controllo degli impulsi, una dipendenza, che spinge le persone ad appiccare fuochi. Il piromane non si rende conto della gravità del suo comportamento, anzi, spesso si mescola ai soccorritori, si ferma a osservare le fiamme, traendone piacere. Quindi il piromane agisce per motivi psicopatologici.

Incendiario = persona che provoca un incendio consapevolmente, per motivi razionali e per interessi personali e materiali. Secondo l’FBI, le motivazioni criminali prevalenti sono: per vandalismo, per vendetta, per profitto, per eccitazione, per sviare le indagini su un altro reato, per distruggere prove. E’ ormai invalso l’uso comune, soprattutto sui mezzi di informazione e di comunicazione, di impiegare indifferentemente i due termini come sinonimi, per indicare il responsabile di un incendio boschivo. In realtà la P.G. deve distinguere attentamente le due fattispecie, in quanto, come detto, la piromania è una “malattia”, quindi il piromane agisce con modalità e con motivazioni assai diverse da un incendiario.}

\end{myenum}

\smallskip
Si noti che l'incendio boschivo colposo (art. 423 bis comma 2 c.p.) e l'incendio colposo (art. 423 e 449 c.p.) sono puniti entrambi con pene da 1 a 5 anni quindi l’art. 423 bis c.p. assume particolare valenza nel caso di azioni dolose (incendiari o piromani).

\\
%
\hline
Principali aspetti procedurali (connessi anche alla pena stabilita)
& Si procede d’ufficio. Competenza: Tribunale. 

\begin{myenum}
\item Comma 1: dolo

%must provide paragraph breaks before each mylist env.
\begin{mylist}
     \item Maggiorenni:

\begin{mylist}
       \item arresto obbligatorio in flagranza di reato (art. 380 c.p.p.);
       \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
       \end{mylist}
    \item Minori:

       \begin{mylist}
       \item arresto facoltativo in flagranza di reato (D.P.R. 448/1988, art. 16 c. 1 e c.3 e art. 23);
       \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
     \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\item Comma 2: colpa

\begin{mylist}
\item Maggiorenni:

   \begin{mylist}
   \item arresto facoltativo in flagranza di reato (art. 381 c.p.p.);
   \item fermo non consentito (art. 384 c.p.);
   \end{mylist}
\item Minori (D.P.R. 448/1988):

   \begin{mylist}
   \item arresto non consentito (D.P.R. 448/1988, art. 16 c.~1 e c.3 e~23);
   \item fermo consentito (art. 384 c.p.).
   \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\end{myenum}
\\
%
\hline
%
Altre note ed informazioni di rilievo&Di norma, sui reati di incendio boschivo procede, per specifica competenza (D.M. Interno 15/08/2017 recante la “Direttiva sui comparti di specialità delle Forze di Polizia e sulla razionalizzazione dei presidi di polizia”), l’Arma dei Carabinieri, alla quale occorre fornire ogni utile contributo informativo ed operativo (cfr. la nota DCPREV n. 10853 del 4-08-2017 ed il Protocollo di Intesa tra il Comandante dell'Arma dei Carabinieri e il Capo del Dipartimento dei Vigili del Fuoco sottoscritto il 5 aprile 2017).\\
%
\hline
% 
Elementi da evidenziare nei rapporti d'intervento& 

\begin{myenum}
\item se le fiamme hanno interessato o potevano sicuramente raggiungere, senza l’intervento VVF, un bosco o una zona coperta d’arbusti, boscaglia o macchia mediterranea come definito dalla legge (D.Lgs. 3 aprile 2018, n. 34, art. 3 comma 3);
\item se si è trattato di un incendio (difficile spegnimento) o principio d’incendio/fuoco riferendosi all’area bruciata, alle squadre impegnate ed al tempo necessario per lo spegnimento;
\item se le presumibili cause sono dolose o colpose ed in base a quali indizi.
\end{myenum}

\end{longtable}
\endgroup  % <-- new
\clearpage % <-- new
\restoregeometry 
} % end of scope of \afterpage directive

\lipsum[1-3]  % this will be typeset on pages 1 and 5

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, thank you very much for the time you dedicated to my problem. Unluckily I'm not able to run the file. Gives me this error "! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable" Probably I should follow your implicit suggestion and try not with longtable. Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: @LucatryingtowriteinLaTex Let me guess: you're running MiKTeX on Windows. Try what's suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33635/4427

Comment: @LucatryingtowriteinLaTex - Does it help if you replace the instruction `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` with `\usepackage{palatino}`?

Comment: Thank you egreg and many thanks to Mico.  Yes, I'm using MiKTeX on Windows. The file still doesn't run. I tried to put Palatino back but is not able to file the file footmisc.sty. I tried the suggestion that egreg give me but I was not able to fix the problem. Unluckily now I have to go to work and I'll try again later. Could someone explain me what  Ulrike Fischer was suggesting me to do?

Comment: @LucatryingtowriteinLaTex - The `footmisc` package isn't strictly necessary (but loading it would be nice...) Incidentally, if this package isn't currently installed on your MikTeX system, you could download and install by running the MPM ("MikTeX Package Manager") utility.