# JHEP class makes everything in math enviroment automatically in a bold font

Tags: boldmath

I am using JHEP class for my physics thesis, but everything written in math environment becomes automatically in bold font. I have tried with different compilers like: TeXworks and TeXmaker. I even send the tex file to my mentor who compiled it on an apple computer and then it works just fine, no bold font.

So the problem has to be on my end, but I am running out of ideas on why it doesn't work. I have tried searching for a solution but it doesn't seem to be a common issue.

Here is the LateX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{jheppub}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}     
Testing $X=56\in \mathcal{H}$    
\begin{equation}    
\label{eq:x}    
\begin{split}    
x &= 1 \,,    
\qquad    
y = 2 \,,    
\\    
z &= 3 \,.    
\end{split}    
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

[link](http://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp)http://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp

and I added a link to the package with the full example provided by JHEP.

Everything inside the math environment is written in a bold font. And I stress that if someone else compiles the document it does not happen.

I added the package  as was recommended and it fixed the rendering issue. But it created an additional problem; it either completely removed the parenthesis/symbols or just shifted them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1 
\usepackage{jheppub} 
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\omega (\alpha X + \beta Y,Z) &= \alpha\omega(X,Z)+\beta\omega(Y,Z)\\
\omega (X,Y)&=-\omega (Y,X) \\
X\minushookup \omega &=0\quad \text{iff} X=0\quad
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{equation}
N^{\perp} = \{X\in V \,|\,\omega (X,Y)=0\, \forall \, Y\in N \}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can we see a minimum working example please? The **preamble**, **begin**, example maths and **end** would be useful to take this further.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Follow next link to find more explanation on what is a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.

Comment: @Fredovich, well that's a start but really we need at least one example of where you get bold font in the maths environment while others don't. Don't forget to include the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Fredovich, please ensure you Display code and links properly, it makes it much easier to read!

Comment: I will do that in the future,

Comment: Just a side note: whether you use TeXworks, Texmaker or some other editor to compile the document shouldn't have any bearing on the result, as these are just frontends to the underlying (La)TeX system, which typically is either MikTeX, TeX Live or MacTeX. Which one do you have? If you're unsure, open the `.log` file and look at the very first line.

Comment: I have MikteX on my computer.

Comment: Could you add the `.log` file to your question as well? I can't guess the cause, but perhaps there are hints in the log that could help someone figure out the problem.

Comment: I don't see the .log file in the folder. How do I access it?

Comment: @Fredovich have you looked in the log subfolder?

Comment: I don't know what is relevant in `.log` file so I just copied the whole file.

Answer (score 4):

Your diagnosis is wrong: it's not the math that appears bold, but the text that appears thin. And `jheppub.sty` has nothing to do with it; it's caused by `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and an issue in your MiKTeX installation.

The problem is that you don't have the Type1 version of the European Modern font, also known as CM-Super; this is stated in your log file by the code

```
<C:\Users\Fredrik\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1095.pk>
```

which means that `pdftex` is creating a bitmap version of the text font (and indeed it will appear thinner in many PDF viewers).

You can solve your problem by adding

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your preamble or properly installing CM-Super. On MiKTeX this issue is very common. See

[How to improve rendering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/how-to-improve-rendering)

[How to run updmap-sys after installing cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/how-to-run-updmap-sys-after-installing-cm-super)

This is the image I get when disabling the Type1 version of `ecrm1095`:

[image]

which should be similar to what you get. In contrast, this is what I get normally

[image]

Comment: I added the package as you recommended and it solved the rendering issue. But it either completely removed all parenthesis or slightly moved them up or down.

Comment: @Fredovich That needs a followup question; please add a minimal example (not the full log file).

Comment: @Fredovich where in the `\usepackage{}` list did you add `\usepackagae{lmodern}`?

Comment: It is on the seventh line.

Comment: try inserting \usepackage{lmodern} earlier (say line 3) and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks for all the help! This has been slowly driving me insane for a couple days now.

Comment: OK, no Problem. It struck me that lmodern might be overriding some of the font configurations from your paper style (JHEP) and thus placing it first in the list would prevent this. Glad it worked.

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson I've converted your answer to a comment here: it's a follow-up to the earlier point you made and doesn't work as a stand-alone answer.