# What font/style is this?

Tags: fonts, pixelated

Consider the following text samples produced with LaTeX:

- sample 1
  [image: default font]
- sample 2
  [image: special font]

Notice the difference in height of letters in sample 2.

Sample 1 is obtained with default font as

```
{\bf Keywords:} magnetic spectrometers, charged particle tracking, particle optics
```

My question is how to produce font style in sample 2. Is the purpose of this style to increase readability of text?

Comment: I'd *never* want to reproduce such a bad typesetting. :)

Comment: This could be due to a rounding error of the renderer software.

Comment: Andrey: it actually appears to be so. Sample 2 is from screen shot from Okular viewer, while sample 1 is from Evince viewer. When the same document is viewed with Adobe Reader the effect is gone. But the strange thing is, that I have already seen this effect on a printed document. And rounding error is usually small (sure it can accumulate in badly written algorithms), but this effect is easily seen by the eye.

Comment: The second sample looks related to the [Cthulhu worshipping man font question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-an-cthulhu-worshipping-mad).

Comment: Is the second sample produced with vector or raster font? Vector format is preferrable, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically) for how to switch.

Comment: I don't have source for sample 2. But when the document that contains sample2 is viewed with e.g. Evince, the effect is gone.

Comment: @liberias: Open file properties in Evince and go to the Fonts tab, if you see any `Type 3` font, then it is _very likely_ a bitmap font.

Comment: There are many `Type 3` fonts there. So bitmap fonts and Okular to reproduce :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some, especially older, documents produced by TeX don't use the today-common vector format for fonts, but rather store them as bitmaps. In the past this had several advantages, such as fast processing and easy rendering. However, the biggest disadvantages are fixed resolution, the inability to precisely scale the font glyphs and to perform antialiasing. Vector format has no such problems and is understood by any modern computer or printer; with proper hinting it can be rendered on screen as precisely as bitmap fonts can, and it can be rendered at any resolution. There is no excuse to use bitmap fonts today.

When rendering a bitmap font on screen, all sorts of rounding or positioning problems can arise, because the only information available to the renderer is a fixed size pixel matrix, which does not scale or rotate well.

With all this said, my advice is to *never* reproduce the given example, and always use vector fonts. See also [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically)