# acm template \left and \right gives error

Tags: brackets, acm

I am using acm template and want `<` and `>` bracket. I checked out some posts regarding this question and they have suggested to use `\left` and `\right`. But the problem is when I use them, they give me error saying `! Missing delimiter (. inserted).` I want to write html code like `<html>`.

I do not want the elongated '<' which is a `delimiter` from `mathsymbols`. I want the simple '<'.

Here is the sample code

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall}

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}

% Document starts
\begin{document}

% Title portion
\title{Some Title}
\author{Some Name
\affil{Some University}}
\maketitle

$\left$ source $\right$
\end{document}
```

But if I use `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$` it doesn't give me any error but gives weird left and right angles.

Comment: What do you what to achieve? What do you want to do with the brackets?

Comment: I want to write html code like in <html>. I have edited the question as well!

Comment: `\left` and `\right` are macros that act on extensible delimiters, which you haven't specified. You're perhaps interested in `$\left\langle\textrm{source}\right\rangle$`?

Comment: Remember that a `\left` must be accompanied by `\right` command.

Comment: This definition works for me: `\newcommand{\braca}[1]{\ifmmode\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle\else$\left\langle{\text{#1}}\right\rangle$\fi}`.  You can use it as `\braca{html}` in text mode or, `$\braca{x = y ^2}$` in math mode (assuming you are loading `amsmath`, if you can `\textrm{}` instead of `\text{}`).

Comment: @Werner: no it gives the same wierd elongated < bracket which is not what I want!

Comment: If you want the smaller angle brackets you can use `\newcommand{\braca}[1]{\ifmmode<{#1}>\else$<\text{#1}>$\fi}`. Then `\braca{html}` should give you want you want.

Comment: Related: [Less pointy angle brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46043/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a command that would represent your HTML tags. Something like `\htmltag`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\htmltag}[1]{%
  \scalebox{.6}[1]{$<$}{\ttfamily#1}\scalebox{.6}[1]{$>$}%
}
\begin{document}
There is \htmltag{source} and also \htmltag{img}.
\end{document}​
```

[`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\scalebox` is used to shrink `<` and `>` horizontally (to 60% of its original width) while maintaining its vertical height. You can substitute this for any other symbol (like `\langle` and `\rangle`) if you wish, and also modify the `.6` horizontal scale parameter or remove the scaling altogether. You don't need to resize the delimiters using `\left` and `\right`.

For now the contents is set using `\ttfamily`. However, depending on the usage, you may wish to put it in an `\mbox` to avoid breaking at the text block boundary if your tags are comprised of multiple words.