# Triangular Parenthesis/Brackets

Tags: brackets

How do I make triangular parenthesis in normal text, like this ?

If I enter it directly it results in spanish exclamation and questionmarks (¡Text¿).

Comment: Search this site for “angle brackets” — I think that’s what you mean.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks, found it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46043/less-pointy-angle-brackets

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).