# Anti aliasing from latex to pdf

Tags: fonts, pdftex

When rendered the text in my pdf is not anti alised. Anyone knows how to do this?

The following example shows my text output compared with output from google docs pdf

[image]

Is it even possible with pdflatex?

Header file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{icomma}
%\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks,pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{fncychap}


\newcommand{\degC}{\ensuremath{\,\unit{^\circ C}}}
\newcommand{\mail}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: it would help if you add the header of your tex file to the post, and tell us how exactly you compile the tex file. I use pdflatex using the pdftex script of TeXShop, and I get nice looking text.

Comment: Is the text rasterized or using a bitmap font? I don't know anything about pdflatex, but those are the only reasons I can think of that would cause aliased text in a PDF.

Comment: When you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you should also load a vector font, for example `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @Richard: I assume you're encountering the problem described in the second question matth linked to. Is this so? Then we'd close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: To clarify terminology: what you're seeing in the images question is *not* antialiasing (at least, not obviously), but simply fonts in a higher resolution (because of using outline fonts and letting the renderer do the rasterization). **Anti-aliasing** refers to using pixels that are not just black-or-white but can be (certain) shades of grey. While it is true that this can give a smoother image (though it's a matter of preference: some people prefer sharp jagged images as in your first image, over blurry edges at the same resolution), it is not true that "smoother" = "anti-aliased".

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no "official" outline fonts for TeXs native Computer Modern Roman fonts in T1 (also called EC) encoding.

For the old OT1 encoding there are the *Blue Sky* fonts, a free set of Type1 fonts which were hand-outlined. You'll see these in the log as follows if you leave out `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

```
</usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
```

For EC encoding there are for instance the *CM Super* fonts, which are also outline fonts, but they are autotraced and the package is huge, so they seem to be missing on some systems. They seem to be included in a full TeXLive install nowadays, so with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` I get:

```
</usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
```

If you don't have the [cm-super](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super) package installed, you'll get bitmap fonts generated from the original *Metafont* sources of the EC fonts, which gives the pixelated effect you are seeing.

Another alternative for T1 encoding is to load the *Latin Modern* fonts with

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

as mentioned in the comment by matth. They are a hand-outlined replacement for Computer Modern, but they look different from the EC fonts in some places.

Comment: I do not know the recent behaviour, but in the past in MiKTeX even on a full install CM Super fonts were not installed automatically. One had to do it by hand with the package installer.

Comment: @Stephan: How do one install a package?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever This depends on your distribution. With TeXLive the script `tlmgr` does a great job!

Answer (score 11):

Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble [is a good thing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc), but sadly [it will load a bitmap font by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically). So in order to hace a nice looking font, you need to load one. Adding microtype makes the type face even nicer. Here is an example of what I put in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
```