# Blurred symbols using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

When I write the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    Given the signal:
    \[
    v(t)=311\cdot\sin(9\cdot10^5t)
    \]
    We know that its period is $ T\approx7\si{\micro\second} $ 
\end{document}
```

The mu produced by `\si{\micro\second}` in detail:

[image]

Which is pixelated. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Add`\usepackage{lmodern}`.  The problem is the `T1` encoding when using the default computer modern font.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you so much! That did the trick

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55096/anti-aliasing-from-latex-to-pdf.  I will vote to close this question as a duplicate.