# Problem with siunitx and T1 fontenc

Tags: siunitx, font-encodings

I'm having a slight problem with `siunitx` and `fontenc`with T1 encoding (I write a lot in Swedish and most people suggest that I should use T1). When I compile to PDF with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` the numbers put in with the `\SI` command are printed bolder than the rest of the text. This really makes them stand out from the rest of the text and it does not look good. If I remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` this does not happen. A minimum example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
The power was \SI{150}{\watt} \\
The power was 150 W
\end{document}
```

I'm using TeXworks on win7. The problem cannot really be seen in the TeXworks preview, but in Adobe Reader it can be seen clearly. Anyone know why this happens or can suggest a workaround?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it looks fine both in TeXmaker and in Adobe Reader. Are you using `pdflatex` to compile your file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using pdflatex to compile.

Comment: Does the same happen if you load `\usepackage{lmodern}`?

Comment: With \usepackage{lmodern} added to the example above the output looks fine. I haven't used Latin modern or any other special font previously but I guess I will have to try it now.

Comment: What fonts are listed at the end of the log file if you don't use lmodern?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What does that line look like?

Comment: @Johan It's a common problem: you don't have the Type1 version for the T1 encoded Computer Modern fonts. Download the CM-Super package (or use Latin Modern fonts as already suggested).

Comment: Ok, now I know how I can solve this. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can someone write up a canonical answer, since it seems to be a problem that has happened before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble [is a good thing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc), 
but sadly [it will load a bitmap font by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically).
To fix this, you should install the [cm-super package or load a vector font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super) (for example `lmodern` or `libertine`).
Adding `microtype` will make the type face a little nicer.

No longer a minimum example, but here is how I would suggest to alter your document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
The power was \SI{150}{\watt} \\
The power was 150 W. \\
Björkö is close to Göteborg, kind of.
\end{document}
```