# Quality is poor due to loaded package

Tags: font-encodings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with siunitx and T1 fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56956/problem-with-siunitx-and-t1-fontenc)

I am using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in my document, but after compiling the quality is poor. The problem seems to be really in the loading of `fontenc` with the `T1` option.

Comment: Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56956/problem-with-siunitx-and-t1-fontenc, I think your question might be a duplicate.

Comment: What is the question? Which fonts ? Which driver? etc.

Comment: I think you refer to pixelated fonts. In that case, just add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the preamble.

Comment: user1450092 Any particular reason you did a rollback to version 2? The edit you reverted was in-line with our editing policies and done by one of our most experienced editors (plus an automated duplicate-link). I did a rollback to the version before your rollback.