# knitr: less/greater than sign displayed as (¡) and (¿)

Tags: r, knitr

I'm a beginner in using knitr to generate a report. I have a R script (see below for an example; BTW I'm using RStudio for all of this) that runs without error and the output is a data frame. My rnw.file looks like this:

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE,message=FALSE>>=
source("test.R")
kable(test.mat)
@
\end{document}
```

which displays the table quite nicely. The only problem I have is with the ">" (greater than) sign in the last column which is shown as "¿".

In found something about using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick here. Having included this, I can start compiling the script but after 10 minutes or so (and w/o it only took me some seconds to compile) I run into an error (exit code: 1).

Also, $>$ will not work for me here, and is displayed as $¿$ in the pdf.
I've already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007986/knitr-less-greater-than-sign-displayed-as-and?noredirect=1#comment50078923_31007986) w/o getting a elegant solution so far.

Thanks in advance!

R.script (saved as "test.R"):

```
temp <- 12
test.mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=2,nrow=1))
test.mat$V1 <- 2
test.mat$V2 <- paste(temp,"subjects > 28 days",sep=" ")
```

Comment: Find out what's the problem with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` by compiling a small document without some R.script.

Comment: Actually, I can't quite figure it out. It's also not working in an ordinary tex.document (using TeXnicCenter).
I tried `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}` and can compile w/o problems, but not solving the initial problem with the ">" symbol being displayed as "¿".

Comment: Well you will have to figure it out. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should work. If it doesn't work in a minimal document your system is broken. Show the log-file.

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain why it is working now, but here is what I found I should use in the preambel:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Found this in another [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56956/problem-with-siunitx-and-t1-fontenc) (not really related to my question), but now I get what I want in the R output (no changes required in the R.script) as well as in the pdf.