# TikZ rotated text looks washed

Tags: tikz-pgf, font-encodings

I got that issue that a rotated text looks washed when you use the package:
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Sadly I can't reject the `fontenc`-package because it has a lot of dependencies to the rest of the project. Is there any workaround to handle this problem?

**without package:**

[image]

**with package:**

[image]

**Example:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%FONTS
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%TIKZ LIBRARYS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[->, >=open triangle 60, thick, color=black]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrow, rounded corners] (0,0) -- node[sloped, anchor=center, above] {I have a} node[sloped, anchor=center, below] {washed style :(} (-4,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example compiles without any problems and the text is not washed out using fontenc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referring to the answer in [Problem with siunitx and T1 fontenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56956/problem-with-siunitx-and-t1-fontenc) , Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble will load a bitmap font by default. To fix this, you should install the cm-super package or load a vector font (for example `lmodern` or `libertine`).

With this, the code changes to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%FONTS
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%TIKZ LIBRARYS
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[->, >=open triangle 60, thick, color=black]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrow, rounded corners] (0,0) -- node[sloped, anchor=center, above] {I have a} node[sloped, anchor=center, below] {washed style :(} (-4,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand the issue. Quiet easy, thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @MarTin you are welcome :)