# Typesetting latin small letter u with diaeresis and caron

Tags: characters

I'm looking for ways to typeset an [ǚ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1da/index.htm).

This character is necessary for typesetting pinyin (汉语拼音, the most common way of transcribing Mandarin Chinese), as it contains syllables such as lǚ (Chinese 铝/鋁; "aluminum").

I've tried

```
\v{\"{u}}
```

and

```
\unichar{474}
```

(from the ucs package)

both of which produce a caron alone followed by ü - not what I want. If there's a way of getting the accents package to do what I want, I can't find it.

This seems like such a basic feature, I'm astonished it's proving so hard to find a way of doing it.

Comment: I would use `ǚ` directly with XeTeX.

Comment: If you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, then `\v{\"{u}}` works.

Comment: You should use [T1 fontenc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc) for accented characters AND load a [vector font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically), for example [latin modern](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super) using `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very few of the fonts available for `pdflatex` have a precomposed ‘ǚ’ character, but it can be built from other pieces. However, TeX doesn't allow to pile up accents in a straightforward way, so it's better to put *one* accent over a precomposed ’ü’, which can be done with T1 encoded fonts. Therefore you can get the character with `\v{\"u}` if you say

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble. You can also use the character directly for input with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ǚ}{\v{ü}}

\begin{document}

Typesetting the `ǚ' character

\end{document}
```

that renders as

[image]

If you're willing to use the Libertine fonts, as suggested by Leo Liu, the definition is slightly different

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ǚ}{\libertineGlyph{uni01DA}}

\begin{document}

Typesetting the `ǚ' character

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different strategy is to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% omitting the following line would use the Latin Modern fonts
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Typesetting the `ǚ' character

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Change the font encoding to use the font with `ü`, then `\v` would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\v{\"u}
\end{document}
```

It is made of two glyphs, however.

Only some of the fonts supports this glyph, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\libertineGlyph{uni01DA}
\end{document}
```

You can also use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX to use unicode glyphs directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
ǚ
\end{document}
```