# Aliasing issues using beamer with pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically)

I'm making a beamer presentation and rendering to a pdf with pdfLaTeX.

When I use the Computer Modern font, the font looks bad due to aliasing. However, when I use the Times font with `\usepackage{times}`, there doesn't seem to be any aliasing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can use the `lmodern` fonts: `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Could you please add to your question some minimal and complete version of your code illustrating this undesired effect?

Comment: Ah, thanks. I discovered the problem was caused by `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, which was in the template I was using.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ECfonts

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly, the FAQ entry http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=type1T1 would appear to be more directly relevant (though easy to find when starting at the last comment).