# What are good ways to make pdflatex output copy-and-pasteable?

Tags: pdftex, languages, copy-paste, font-encodings

One frequent aspect of `pdflatex` output that could be improved is to what extent one can select text output from the generated pdf-file and copy-and-paste it. This is essentially an issue of having the right output encoding. There are at least two important aspects to this:

- In the ideal case, Unicode would be the output encoding.
- Ligature glyphs (such as ﬁ) are ideally de-ligated in the output (here: "fi").

It seems that output encodings are specified through the `fontenc` package. What is the range of possible output encodings, and most importantly: **Is there a way to specify a Unicode output encoding and one that deals with ligatures in the intended way?**

(Note: It is important to distinguish *output* from *input* encodings. How to use different *input* encodings in LaTeX has been documented widely. My understanding is that this is best handled by the `inputenx` package, as it supersedes the `inputenc` package.)

---

**Quick guide to the solutions:** The information in the answers and answer threads is a bit distributed, so here the short summary: one approach is to use `\input glyphtounicode` together with `\pdfgentounicode=1`; the other approach is to use `cmap`/`mmap`.

**Addendum:** Sometimes one will need to load the package `accsupp` and enclose one's macro definition in `\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=<codepoint>}`[...]`\EndAccSupp{}` to generate a specific code point. See the caveat about non-BMP code points [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70712/14996) and the fix (starting from `accsupp` version v0.4, 2012/11/18) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70712/how-do-i-paste-codepoints-outside-of-the-basic-multilingual-plane-with-accsupp-o#comment178339_70712), which provides the new `unichar` package option.

Comment: Please avoid creating new tags when there are very similar ones existing already (output-encodings -> font-encodings; locales -> languages). If you think another name for that tag would be better, post it as a question on [meta].

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the info; what is the best place to look for a comprehensive list of tag definitions and differentiation?

Comment: When I'm asking a question, I start typing in what I think would be a good tag; if an existing tag pops up, I use it. If not, I try to think of synonyms. Seeing the some 20k questions we have, you can be pretty sure that there are existing tags for the most important concepts. The tag wiki excerpts and the tag wikis (if they exist yet) give you a rough idea if you're using the tag for the right area. If they don't exist, take a look at the questions that are tagged with that tag. A rough rule of thumb really is: Don't create new tags. There are numerous exceptions to this rule, of course.

Comment: @doncherry Another good method that I've discovered to work quite well for me is to look at the tags of the "Questions that may already have your answer".

Comment: `\usepackage{ae}` is a partial solution - the copy'n'paste doesn't produce gibberish, but characters gets copied decomposed (e.g. 'ó' -> '`o').

Comment: Even with `\usepackage{lmodern}`, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (a combination which permits to copy many characters, including those given in the OP examples, from the PDF), copying `\succeq` from the resulting PDF does not work. Adding `\input glyphtounicode \pdfgentounicode=1` makes it work: `\succeq` gets copied to unicode ⪰.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Do you Know the package cmap (look at [CTAN:cmap](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cmap/))? It does this for you.
Load it with `\usepackage{cmap}` as first package.

*Update*: I did a little research and found some hints how to use `cmap` or `mmap`. *Result*: `cmap` and `mmap` can't handle fonts based on virtual fonts (files `*.vf` or `*.vpl` in the font directory). So if your used font needs virtual fonts `cmap` or `mmap` can't work. You should better use `glyphtounicode`. This [hint](http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2087&group_id=106&atid=495) could be useful.

BTW: `cmap` is based on the character maps of Adobe. See PDF reference [Version 1.6](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html) for more information.

*Update2*: With `texdoc encguide` you will get a document describing the T1 Cork encoding. There you will find a table showing all the glyphs you can directly write in your pdf file. Because there is a glyph `ä` you can find `ä` in your pdf file. If there is no glyph `ä` LaTeX has to build it with two characters: `"a`. You will see `ä` in your pdf file but you can't find it (to search `"a` could help; copy and paste give you this back).

*Update 3*: `glyphtounicode` supports only the T1-encoding, [`cmap`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap) supports many more encodings. One advantage of `glyphtounicode` is that one can add with one command more glyphs which haven't yet been included in the official list. More information about `\glyphtounicode` is here: [tb91thanh-fonts.pdf](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb29-1/tb91thanh-fonts.pdf). Make sure to get the latest version of `glyphtounicode.tex` from [LCDF Type Software](http://www.lcdf.org/type/) and see [this caveat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97331/miktex-order-of-precedence-for-duplicate-files) on how to properly use it.

Comment: @user14996 `glyphtounicode` functionality that `cmap` does not offer (f.ex. support for virtual fonts). But `cmap` offers more encodings. If you only need T1-encoding, use `glyphtounicode`.

Comment: @LoverofStructure What makes you think `\pdfgentounicode` only supports T1 encoding?

Comment: @LevBishop I don't remember how this fact made it into here; I think it was merged from another answer or comment. Please correct if justified.

Comment: @Sveinung Perhaps you remember about the T1-part (see previous comment by Lev Bishop)?

Comment: +1 for a working answer; however, the answer would be improved if it said what cmap is/does.  As is, I need to click the external link to get a description.

Comment: `cmap` doesn't seem to work with `\usepackage{libertinus}` -- is the order important?

Answer (score 18):

As you don't provide a minimal example, I am not sure if this really addresses your problem.  Have you tried loading `glyphtounicode.tex`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}

ff ffi ffl ä ü ö ß

auffallen

\end{document}
```

However, even without using `glyphtounicode`, `pdftotext` produces unicode text on my system.  With `glyphtounicode`, the ligatures get de-ligated.

Comment: Thanks for the starter code. Some things: *With* the `inputenc`-line it is unclear what the difference is if I compile the code with or without the two `glyphtounicode`-lines. Therefore I have replaced your first text line with `ff ffi ffl \"a \"u \"o \ss`, removed the `inputenc`-line, saved it in ANSI format and compiled (*with* and *without* the `fontenc`-line). Result: (1) **With** the `fontenc`-line, it oddly makes no difference in the output whether we use the two `glyphtounicode`-lines. ...

Comment: ... (2) **Without** the `fontenc`-line, the two `glyphtounicode`-lines are required for sensible output, but even then the ligatures will copy-and-paste as `¨a ¨u ¨o`.

Comment: **Update** (a correction to my very first assertion ("*With* the `inputenc`-line [...] two `glyphtounicode`-lines.")): With the original `äöüß`-chars and the `inputenc`-line, the results of my experimentation is actually exactly the same: **With** the `fontenc`-line, the two `glyphtounicode`-lines don't make a difference; **without** the `fontenc`-line, the two `glyphtounicode`-lines indeed enable proper copy-and-pasting but the umlaut characters paste as `¨a ¨o ¨u`, which is surely not as intended. So I am unclear about the exact role of `glyphtounicode` and its interaction with `fontenc`.

Comment: Which font are you using? I am using `minionpro` and never experienced any interaction. With `fontenc` and without `glyphtounicode`, I got strange result when copying and pasting from the .PDF-files.

Comment: By the way, without `fontenc`, accented characters are composed of a letter and a diacrit (ä is ¨a etc.) so they copy/paste ‘correctly’.

Comment: @Sveinung I think you could argue that they do paste correctly, though you could also argue they should paste with a Unicode combining diaeresis. As for my setup, I've just started exactly with Michael's code and then modified it as I described. // Basically my question is *why `glyphtounicode` doesn't make a difference in output or pasting behavior when the `fontenc`-line is used*.

Comment: @user14996 I have updated my answer with some of my own findings.

Comment: @user14996 Still not satisfied with the answers?

Comment: @Sveinung Many thanks! I ended up accepting Kurt's answer because of his summary research, but your contribution is valuable too. Too bad attributing partial points is so cumbersome in SE (works only with bounty mechanics). // One more thing about `"a`: I'd strongly argue that "correct" pasting behavior yields compact characters whenever possible. That means when the output encoding is Unicode, I'd prefer `ä` over either clumsy `"a` or "a with a combining diaeresis thereafter". But you can justify `"a` if the output encoding doesn't have "ä", so you're indeed right about the case w/o fontenc.

Comment: @user14996 Therefore I put the word correctly in citation marks, to emphasize that correctly should not be interpret literally.

Comment: When loading `T1 font encoding`, you should also load a vector font like `lmodern` as discussed in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1293

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `memoir`, you can compile your document with the option `ms`. The output is like something that are written with a typewriter, but since it has no hyphenation, it is easy to copy and paste the text for reuse in another program, such as Word or LibreOffice Writer.

I often use this option as a quick and dirty way to get the text in a LaTeX document into Word.

Since memoir use 1.5 line spacing in `ms`-mode, it is important to set the number of lines per pages to a number that is not overfilling the page.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{ms,article}{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\setulmargins{*}{*}{1,5}
\setlength{\textheight}{32\baselineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout[lines]


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-21]

\end{document}
```

*EDIT*: user14996 asked: *Why `glyphtounicode` doesn't make a difference in output or pasting behavior when the fontenc-line is used*?

The answer to that is: It depends on your font. I use `MinionPro`, which use minuscule figures (`oldstylenums`) as standard. I also use spaced small capitals. With the `glyphtounicode`, but without the  `fontenc`, loaded, Norwegian characters (æøå ÆØÅ) is not copied correctly from the PDF-file. On the other hand, all numbers and small caps can be copied and pasted. If I do the opposite,  remove `glyptounicode` but keep `fontenc`, the numbers comes out as Greek characters, and the small caps disappear. Also, all ligatures (fi ffi fj) disappear.

Using `cmap` in stead of `glyphtounicode` does not help.

So the answer is that sometimes `fontenc` is the only package you need, but if you use special features in a font (small caps, old style figures etc.) which require virtual fonts, you need to load  `glyphtounicode`. `cmap` does not support virtual fonts. Sometimes not even `glyphtounicode` solves all problems.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem for quite some time in the past. I solved it in a way which worked well for me, and I found the following notes about it:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I agree that `fontenc` (as encoding of the *output*) is what you would expect. However, I have been using the `german` package as well. And that tends to assemle german umlauts as strange custom tokens (like an 'a' with two dots drawn on top of it rather than the correct unicode char). I used `inputenc` to fix that.

I understand that this answer addresses mainly the question "How can I make pdflatex output copy-pastable pdfs?". It leaves the predicate "good" for others who might be able to answer your specific questions. But perhaps this is still useful as it seemed to work fine, or at least fine enough.

Comment: @Michael There seems to be some interaction between `glyphtounicode` and `fontenc`, which I haven't yet figured out. I'll be happy about any insights about the precise nature of this interaction.

Answer (score 4):

I am not proficient in latex, but in order to achieve copyable Cyrillic PDFs you can use a document of the following kind.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T2B]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T2C]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Кирилица

\end{document}
```

**T2A**, **T2B** and **T2C** are sets of different variants of Cyrillic alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

It is been a while but I'd like to contribute to offer a solution for LyX.

Type:

```
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble (Document-> Preferences).

Then activate under languages (Document->Preferences->Language) for the encoding: "Different -> Unicode(utf8).

Close and save.

Comment: What does the encoding `T2A` do?

Comment: Well the problem of uncopyable PDFs only appears, when you want to use Cyrillic letters. T2A activates Cyrillic. :)

Comment: @Lukas The Latin alphabet is affected too when you encounter things like Ligature glyphs.