# How can I get a PDF with copyable text if I need to use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, font-encodings, copy-paste

Consider the following situation:

- A .tex file with the following content:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \begin{document}
  Let it be.
  \end{document}
  ```
- The file is compiled by pressing ALT + 6 on Kile 2.1.2, using Ubuntu 12.10
- The PDF file is opened by pressing ALT + 7, which executes Evince 3.6.0
- All the PDF content is selected/copied by pressing CTRL + A and CTRL + C

For some reason (unknown to me), if I paste such content on any text editor (e.g. this input field, gedit, kile or kate) I get

```
▲❡t ✐t ❜❡✳
✶
```

and if I remove the command `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and compile the file again, I get a copy-able PDF, from which I can copy the  correct text

```
Let it be
```

How can I get a PDF with copy-able text if I need to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: When I compile this I can copy and paste from this even while using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: It works whether I run `latex->dvips->ps2pdf' or whether I run `pdflatex`.  Do you know what compiling commands your key-commands are bound to?

Comment: @A.Ellett this depends on your pdf viewer application. In the absence of a ToUnicode CMap in the PDF (see the linked duplicate question for ways to generate one), the viewer has to make some guesses/assumptions: different viewers make different guesses and may get it right in some cases and wrong in others. [Some methods of doing this are actually patented](http://www.google.com/patents/US20060288281)

Comment: @A.Ellett: On Settings > Configure Kile > Tools > Build, the config for PDFLaTeX is:

    Command: `pdflatex`
    Options: `-interaction=nonstopmode '%source'`

and for ViewPDF it is:

    Command: `evince`
    Options: `'%target'`

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{cmap}`, as suggested by Kurt [in his reply to the other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64198/25761) works for me. Thanks!