# Defining scalable "white curly brackets" {| and |} (⦃ and ⦄)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, scaling

**I would like to construct what Unicode calls "white curly brackets" that are in addition scalable.** They look like ⦃ (≈`{|`) and ⦄ (≈`|}`) and have Unicode codepoints U+2983 and U+2984.

`unicode-math` has them as `\lBrace` and `\rBrace`, but (1) I don't presently use XeTeX or LuaTeX and (2) their design (shown in [`unimath-symbols.pdf`](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) on pages 3-4) is not to my liking: the brace part is too fat for my taste, and I would like the vertical bar to not leave any protrusions. I am trying to have them visually match the parentheses `\llparenthesis`, `\rrparenthesis`, `\llbracket`, and `\rrbracket` from `stmaryrd`.

Right now I am using a makeshift definition, which is sufficient for now, but the symbols don't scale (in general or with `\left`/`\right`). Here is sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket,llparenthesis,rrparenthesis]{stmaryrd} % for comparison with 4 similar parenthesis symbols
\usepackage{accsupp} % for ensuring the right Unicode codepoint upon pasting

\newcommand*{\llbrace}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2983}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char102}%
    \mathchoice{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.3mu}{\mkern-4.8mu}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char106}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\newcommand*{\rrbrace}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2984}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char106}%
    \mathchoice{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.3mu}{\mkern-4.8mu}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char103}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}


\begin{document}

\noindent
ok:
\(\displaystyle\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)
\(\textstyle\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)
\(\scriptstyle\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)
\(\scriptscriptstyle\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)

\noindent
ok:
\(\displaystyle \llbrace \frac{a}{b} \rrbrace\)
\(\textstyle\llbrace \frac{a}{b} \rrbrace\)
\(\scriptstyle\llbrace \frac{a}{b} \rrbrace\)
\(\scriptscriptstyle\llbrace \frac{a}{b} \rrbrace\)

\noindent
incorrectly scaled (\verb|\scriptsize|): {\scriptsize\(\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)} (large magnification required)

\noindent
incorrectly scaled (\verb|\tiny|): {\tiny\(\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)}

\noindent
\verb|\left| and \verb|\right| not possible before \verb|\llbrace| and \verb|\rrbrace|: \\
\indent \(\llbrace \left\llbracket\left\{\left[(a) \cdot bc^{2^3}\right]^4\right\}^5\right\rrbracket \rrbrace\)
% Note: This is also not possible with \llparenthesis and \rrparenthesis from stmaryrd.

\noindent
for comparison: \(\llparenthesis x \rrparenthesis, \llbracket x \rrbracket, \llbrace x \rrbrace; (x), [x], \{x\}\)

\end{document}
```

Lines 1 and 2 look just right with the present setup. Lines 3 and 4 demonstrate that my definitions don't scale. Lines 5a/b gives an example of where I would like to be able to use `\left` and `\right`. Line 6 juxtaposes different types of parentheses for visual comparison.

**Is there an easy way to scale the glyphs I have constructed myself? Or is designing new glyphs the only way?** While the vertical part of my glyphs doesn't leave any protrusions, the "brace part being too fat" part of my problem isn't being addressed by my code. With this in mind: I recognize that it might not be that easy to make the brace part of the glyph thinner (though if you can, more power to you), but I think that any solution that **addresses the scaling problem for any manually constructed glyph cluster** will be a valuable contribution to the community.

---

For a slightly different setup (original example code) with

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}[2006/09/13]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket,llparenthesis,rrparenthesis]{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{accsupp}
```

in the preamble, one needs `\mkern-5.7mu` in the fourth argument to `\mathchoice` for "correct" scaling. To see what goes wrong in that case, it's best to include a line such as `discontinuous small symbols in a footnote\footnote{\(\scriptscriptstyle\llbrace \frac{a}{b} \rrbrace\)}`. This might help a potential answerer test things out.

Comment: If I look at all the packages you use: this is not what I'd call an MWE `:-)` Or are there particular reasons why all these packages are relevant to your problem?

Comment: @HendrikVogt After spending an hour playing with the `\mkern-..mu`-values in my present document, you really think I should try recalibrating things just to be able to write `\documentclass{article}`? `memoir` is a tasteful class, and using `fix-cm` and `fixltx2e` is good practice anyways (this can be relevant depending on the font tricks you're using). Without `amsmath` the glyph positioning already looks different (try it out). `[12pt]` can be done away with (again, at the cost of different letter positioning), but I don't think there is value in omitting this now just for saving 4 letters.

Comment: @HendrikVogt But if you want to edit out `accsupp` (using it here would be [useful](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64188/14996) and good practice) or other lines, I very much and strongly encourage you to make the necessary constructive edits ... *As indicated*, the sample code is showing one possible way to get the two symbols approximately right. A possible solution that manages to scale just those two symbols will or should be independent anyways; and if the only solution is to stick together glyphs in a totally different way, this will be so even more so.

Comment: Regarding `accsupp`: It's definitely not relevant to your problem, but I'm happy that I learned from you about that package and its usage `:-)` Still, the point about an MWE is not to show good practice. You can omit the `fix`es, the `txfonts`, and you can also replace `memoir` with `article` - no need to recalibrate anything, just try it!

Comment: @HendrikVogt Okay, I will try :-) Gimme a few minutes ...

Comment: @HendrikVogt: `Memoir` is a standard class, it is a bit larger than article but other use `scrbook` without getting any complaint. `accsup` could be relevant to the problem: Its use could affect the spacing. `fix-cm` *does* contain settings which affects math fonts (OMS + OML) encoding. Imho the example is quite good.

Comment: `@Lover:` Oh, wow, I completely missed the different spacing for the smaller sizes!! By the way I do like your question a lot. @Ulrike: OK, maybe I was a bit misled by my MikTeX installation asking to download several missing packages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With `scalerel`, you can definitely take care of the `\left` `\right` problem.  And I think I took care of the tine & scriptsize problem, too.  What I did was to save a good copy of the normalsize bbraces in boxes, so that `\lxbrace` and `\rxbrace` would place the boxes containing good copies of the bbraces.  I then used scalerel to scale these boxes to the desired sizes.  So, essentially `\lxbrace` and `\rxbrace` replaced your `\llbrace` and `\rrbrace`.

The key here is that I am scaling the `\normalsize` version of the bbraces, whereas what I think happened to your original glyph is that tiny versions of a LaTeX brace are not merely scaled versions of the normalsize brace, but modified (by LaTeX) for legibility.  But inyour case, you don't want modifications to your glyph's components as they are shrunk.

Lastly, scalerel is able to emulate the `\left \right` thingy to scale your brace up to the proper size, whatever that might be.  I did use a width-limited scale, to avoid the scaled brace looking too clunky.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket,llparenthesis,rrparenthesis]{stmaryrd}
\parskip 1ex
\parindent 0ex
\usepackage{accsupp} % for ensuring the right Unicode codepoint upon pasting

\newcommand*{\llbrace}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2983}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char102}%
    \mathchoice{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.3mu}{\mkern-4.8mu}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char106}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\newcommand*{\rrbrace}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2984}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char106}%
    \mathchoice{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.05mu}{\mkern-4.3mu}{\mkern-4.8mu}%
    \textnormal{\usefont{OMS}{lmr}{m}{n}\char103}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\lXbrace}
\savebox{\lXbrace}{$\llbrace$}
\newsavebox{\rXbrace}
\savebox{\rXbrace}{$\rrbrace$}
\def\lxbrace{\scalerel*{\usebox{\lXbrace}}{\llbrace}}
\def\rxbrace{\scalerel*{\usebox{\rXbrace}}{\rrbrace}}

\noindent
\verb|\tiny|: {\tiny\(\llbrace abc \rrbrace\)}
{\tiny\(\lxbrace abc \rxbrace\)} 
 $<-$scale of original brace

  \verb,ORIGINAL:,%
\indent \(\llbrace \left\llbracket\left\{\left[(a) \cdot
bc^{2^3}\right]^4\right\}^5\right\rrbracket \rrbrace\)
\\\verb,FIXED:   ,%
\def\core{ \left\llbracket\left\{\left[(a) \cdot
bc^{2^3}\right]^4\right\}^5\right\rrbracket}%
\indent \(\scalerel[1.5ex]{\lxbrace}{\core}\scalerel*[1.5ex]{\rxbrace}{\core}\)
bbraces scaled, but limited to 1.5ex width

\end{document}
```

I edited the original image (via zoom) to show how scalerel can take the bbraces and vertically scale them to fit the mathematical object they enclose.  The top equation is without scalerel, the bottom with it.

[image]

I have added also a zoom on the `\tiny` size objects, so that one can see the effect of scaling the normalsize glyph rather than letting LaTeX scale both the strut and the brace and then sticking them together.  The left version is letting LaTeX scale the glyphs that compose the character, while the right image is letting scalerel package scale the `\normalsize` character to `\tiny` proportions.

[image]

---

Based on request to be able to provide horizontal compression, to help make glyphs better match comparable counterparts in the literature, I upgraded the scalerel package today (to v1.3), adding the following composite commands

```
\newcommand\scaleleftright[4][99in]{%
  \if.#2\def\leftarg{\bl@nk}\else\def\leftarg{#2}\fi%
  \if.#4\def\rightarg{\bl@nk}\else\def\rightarg{#4}\fi%
  \scalerel[#1]{\leftarg}{#3}\scalerel*[#1]{\rightarg}{#3}%
}
\newcommand\stretchleftright[4][10000]{%
  \if.#2\def\leftarg{\bl@nk}\else\def\leftarg{#2}\fi%
  \if.#4\def\rightarg{\bl@nk}\else\def\rightarg{#4}\fi%
  \stretchrel[#1]{\leftarg}{#3}\stretchrel*[#1]{\rightarg}{#3}%
}

\newcommand\hstretch[2]{\stretchrel*{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}{#2}}

\newcommand\vstretch[2]{\stretchrel*{#2}{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}
```

The `...leftright` commands provide automated scaling for symbols in the manner of mathmode's `\left` and `\right` commands.  But the `\hstretch` and `\vstretch` commands allow for the glyph stretching that was desired by the user.  Using his prior example,  I further refined the definition of his white-curly-braces symbol as

```
\def\lxbrace{%
   \hstretch{0.6}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\lXbrace}}{\llbrace}}}
\def\rxbrace{%
   \hstretch{0.6}{\scalerel*{\usebox{\rXbrace}}{\rrbrace}}}
```

which provided a 40% horizontal compression of his composite-glyph character.  Thus, to compare (now in normal, not tiny size), my original correction to this latest correction:

[image]

Comment: What an impressive solution! Your `scalerel` package seems perfect for my problem.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I updated the scalerel package today (v1.2) to add `\scaleleftright` and `\stretchleftright` composite commands to mimic the `\left ... \right` functionality of math mode, since not all symbols will scale using that syntax of math mode.  This isn't new functionality, rather just convenience of syntax.

Comment: In your documentation, you ask for ideas about horizontal scaling. This isn't really an implementation idea, but as an idea for an application: one could make the curly portion of the "white curly brackets" shown/constructed here a bit thinner so that they match up better with the other two parenthesis pairs from `stmaryrd` that I'm using. At least for ordinary font sizes this difference is noticeable. For larger font sizes one could then horizontally stretch them again (with a limit, like what you already have).

Answer (score 0):

A poor man's approach. It probably doesn't fit the bill:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\Huge

$\left\lbrace\mkern-2mu\middle| ABC^{\left\lbrace\mkern-2mu\middle| XYZ\middle|\mkern-2mu\right\rbrace} \middle|\mkern-2mu\right\rbrace$

\end{document}
```

[image: braces]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Actually I think your answer is an example of what doesn't work :-) (really no offense), so if you could edit your answer to (1) say this and (2) state what your approach is, I think it deserves an upvote for its illustrative value. (I will then also delete this comment.)

Comment: @LoverofStructure three years later, you didn't delete it ;)

Comment: @SkeletonBow The user in question didn't edit his answer in response to my comment, so I would say we let my comment stand as-is.