# Use custom brackets

Tags: brackets

For my thesis I need particular brackets for defining some operators. I found `\llceil`, `\rrceil`, `\llfloor` and `\rrfloor` in the [`stmaryrd` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.pdf), which are just what I was looking for. Unfortunately, they do not support `\left` and `\right` and therefore they look very ugly with tall formulas. Probably they are not designed for such formulas.

Is there a simple way to make them supporting `\left` and `\right` or to define other brackets that do support them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks for pointing out. I'll be more precise in future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not perfect, because the stretching of the glyph thickens up the horizontal stroke, but it may be sufficient for your needs.  The `\stretchleftright{}{}{}` macro will stretch arguments 1 and 3 to meet the vertical extent of argument 2.

A related answer is [Defining scalable "white curly brackets" {| and |} (⦃ and ⦄)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and/100993#100993)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[
\llceil x\rrceil  ~~~\llfloor y \rrfloor
\]
\[
\stretchleftright{\llceil}{\frac{x^2}{y_2}}{\rrceil}~~~
\stretchleftright{\llfloor}{\sqrt{y^2}}{\rrfloor}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The other approach is to stick two of the normal "ceil"s together.  This will avoid the thickening of the horizontal stroke, but it must be matched with another "double" glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\llceil{\left\lceil\kern-3.5pt\left\lceil}
\def\rrceil{\right\rceil\kern-3.5pt\right\rceil}
\begin{document}
\[
\llceil\frac{x^2}{y_2}\rrceil
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. I used the second approach, but with 3pt instead of -3.5pt, in order to make the presence of both brackets more visible for small arguments. Thank you very much, you saved my notation!

Answer (score 6):

The `\llceil`, `\rrceil`, `\llfloor` and `\rrfloor` symbols of `stmaryrd` are available at a single size.

You can define macros `\dceil` and `\dfloor` that take an argument; with `\dceil*` automatically extensible delimiters are produced and a numeric optional argument adds some negative kern between the two `\lceil` or `\rceil` that are used. Without the `*`, the optional argument can be `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`. The same for `\dfloor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse,stmaryrd}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dceil}{sO{0}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \spiros_ceilfloor_ext:nnnn { #2 } { #3 } { \lceil } { \rceil }
   }
   { 
    \spiros_ceilfloor:nnnn { #2 } { #3 } { \lceil } { \rceil }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\dfloor}{sO{0}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \spiros_ceilfloor_ext:nnnn { #2 } { #3 } { \lfloor } { \rfloor }
   }
   {
    \spiros_ceilfloor:nnnn { #2 } { #3 } { \lfloor } { \rfloor }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spiros_ceilfloor_ext:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \left#3
  \mkern-\muskip_eval:n { 4.5mu + #1mu }
  \left#3
  #2
  \right#4
  \mkern-\muskip_eval:n { 4.5mu + #1mu }
  \right#4
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \spiros_ceilfloor:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \mathopen{\str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 } { #1 }#3}
  \mkern\spiros_kern:n { #1 }
  \mathopen{\str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 } { #1 }#3}
  #2
  \mathclose{\str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 } { #1 }#4}
  \mkern\spiros_kern:n { #1 }
  \mathclose{\str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 } { #1 }#4}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \spiros_kern:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    { \big }{ -4.5mu }
    { \Big }{ -5.5mu }
    { \bigg }{ -6.5mu }
    { \Bigg }{ -7.5mu }
   }
   { -4.5mu }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
\llceil x\rrceil\\
\dceil*{x} \quad
\dceil*{\frac{x}{2}}\quad
\dceil*[1]{\frac{x}{2}}\quad
\dceil*[3]{\frac{\dfrac{x}{2}}{\dfrac{y}{3}}}
\]
\[
\dceil{x}\quad
\dceil[\big]{x}\quad
\dceil[\Big]{x}\quad
\dceil[\bigg]{x}\quad
\dceil[\Bigg]{x}
\]
\[
\llfloor x\rrfloor\\
\dfloor*{x} \quad
\dfloor*{\frac{x}{2}}\quad
\dfloor*[1]{\frac{x}{2}}\quad
\dfloor*[3]{\frac{\dfrac{x}{2}}{\dfrac{y}{3}}}
\]
\[
\dfloor{x}\quad
\dfloor[\big]{x}\quad
\dfloor[\Big]{x}\quad
\dfloor[\bigg]{x}\quad
\dfloor[\Bigg]{x}
\]
\end{document}
```

The result seems acceptable without correction in the case of `\dceil*` and `\dfloor*` up to a certain size (corresponding to `\bigg`); after it a correction is needed.

Maybe the correction could be made automatic based on the size of the mandatory argument.

[image]

Comment: Very impressive!  (as always)

Comment: This is indeed a perfect solution. The brackets look really perfect at all sizes. Unfortunately, this solution is not backward compatible, in the sense that my tex code that uses `\llceil` would have to be adapted eveywhere in order to make use of your proposed commands (and automatic replacemnt is not an option with my document). For my new documents I will use it, if I still need these brackets.

Comment: @Spiros You can leave `\llceil` and similar commands, since at the normal size the result is pretty the same.