# Gauss brackets with double vertical lines

Tags: symbols, brackets, stmaryrd, nath

I would like to have commands for left- and right gauss brackets which have a double vertical line, but otherwise behave exactly like `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`. In particular, they should come in various sizes and other things should stay unchanged.

I found two candidates, which are both not optimal, unfortunately:

- `\llfloor` and `\rrfloor` in the package  `stmaryrd`. Unfortunately they do not understand preceeding `\left` and `\right` commands. My impression is they are fixed size.
- `\lFloor` and `\rFloor` in the package `nath`. They come in different sizes, but the problem is that including the package `nath` introduces automatic sizing behaviour of all symbols of parantheses-type. This might be interesting, but for the moment this change is just too radical for my taste.

Comment: Please do you have available a MWE for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140055/use-custom-brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option if you don't want to use any packages other than `amsmath` would be to place two `\lfloor`s next to each other with a little negative space between:

[image]

This has the advantage of not thickening the horizontal portion of the delimiter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\gaussbr}[1]{%
    \left\lfloor\hspace{-.33em}\left\lfloor #1\right\rfloor\hspace{-.33em}\right\rfloor%
    }

\begin{document}

\[
\gaussbr{A}\gaussbr{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n}
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can adjust the amount of negative space to your liking.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Werner for providing a solution for [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109699/how-can-i-create-a-new-extensible-symbol/109701#109701).

A rather quick fix using [`scalerel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) would be the following.

Conveniently, [`scalerel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) provides `\scaleleftright[<max width>]{<left obj>}{<stuff>}{<right obj>}` (and a comparable `\stretchleftright`) for scaling/stretching both `<left obj>` and `<right obj>` to the height of `<stuff>` (constrained, if required and optional, to a width of `<max width>`). Here's a quick example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel, stmaryrd} % http://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel

\newcommand{\gaussbracket}[1]{\stretchleftright{\llfloor}{#1}{\rrfloor}}

\begin{document}
\[ \gaussbracket{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very very good. I have really appreciated your code.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I wanted. I wanted a pair of commands, one for left and one for right bracket, which can be resized by \big, \Big, etc. Also, the scaled symbol does not look so good (too thick vertical line).

Comment: @azimut. I think the linked question would be an interesting read then, I wouldn't know how to make a non extensible delimiter extensible.