# Function of interpretation by assignment g

Tags: linguistics, logic

How can I make this function in LaTeX:

[image]

I tried with `\Vmatrix` as:

```
$\begin{Vmatrix} \bullet \end{Vmatrix}^{\mathscr{M}_i,g}$
```

but its not the same. If you can help me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is this a function that's dependent on `i` and `g` (not `M`)?

Answer (score 6):

The `stmaryrd` package has these symbols ready to go.

If one also needs the double brace, which is not in the `stmaryrd` package, an alternate solution is offered at [Defining scalable "white curly brackets" {| and |} (⦃ and ⦄)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and/100993#100993)

Here is the MWE for the double brackets and parens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \llbracket\cdot\rrbracket^{\mathcal{M}_i,g}\quad
  \left\llbracket\strut\cdot\right\rrbracket^{\mathcal{M}_i,g}
\]
\[
  \llparenthesis\cdot\rrparenthesis^{\mathcal{M}_i,g}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, the one should note that the double-bracket is scalable using `\left\llbracket...\right\rrbracket` syntax.  On the other hand, the double-parens are not scalable with that syntax.  However, the `\stretchleftright{}{}{}` syntax of the `scalerel` package can emulate the behavior somewhat.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left\llbracket\frac{x}{y}\right\rrbracket^{\mathcal{M}_i,g}
\]
\[
  {\stretchleftright{\llparenthesis}{\frac{x\strut}{y\strut}}{\rrparenthesis}}^{\mathcal{M}_i,g}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see why using the `only` option; it was useful several years ago, when memory was scarce.

Comment: @egreg I didn't know whether `stmaryrd` was anything like `MnSymbol`, taking over the whole symbol set or not.  So, since I knew this option to be available, I thought it safer.

Comment: No, `stmaryrd` provides a set of new symbols and redefines nothing. I seem to remember that a package loads `stmaryrd` with the `only` option, making it very difficult to use other symbols from the package. Since memory is not a problem any longer, just load the full set.

Answer (score 4):

You can "concatenate" two square brackets using a negative `\mkern`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\[
  [\mkern-3.5mu[
  \cdot
  ]\mkern-3.5mu]
  ^
  {\mathcal{M}_i,g}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful for me. I did it with \usepackage{amsmath} and $$, it work perfect.