# Double-struck parentheses

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, brackets, mathtools

We can use `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` (provided by the `stmaryrd` package) to generate double brackets. My questions are:

- how we can generate double-struck **parentheses** in the **same** style as the single-struck bracket version?
- how we can generate double-struck **parentheses** such that we can write two elements vertically (like the vector format)?

Two things are important:

1. The distance between two parenthesis which should be as nice as in the `\llbracket \rrbracket`.
2. The top and bottom of the two parenthesis should touch each other like `\llbracket \rrbracket`.

Edit: This question in some aspects can be the counterpart for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553463/120126) replacing by **parenthesis**.

Comment: Would `$\llparenthesis x \rrparenthesis$` or `$\left(\!\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\!\right)$` work?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily: Thanks. Not actually. The one created by '\llbracket \rrbracket' is very neat. I need to have something in that style.

Comment: sure! maybe you should include a sample image of how you would like the result to look like. You can hand-draw it (be precise please).

Comment: @M.AlJumaily: I just described it. You can consider there is parenthesis instead of bracket in $\llbracket \rrbracket$ and could be vertical taking two elements like vector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107252/double-square-brackets)

Comment: @Thruston: Not actually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function of interpretation by assignment g](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308973/function-of-interpretation-by-assignment-g)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Not actually.

Comment: I'm not aware of the existence of any double-struck round parentheses that can be scaled via `\left` and `\right` directives. In this regard, the macros `\llparenthesis` and `\rrparenthesis` of the `stmaryrd` or `stix` packages are *very different* from `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`.

Comment: @Mico: I see. Thanks.

Comment: A possible mechanism has been shown in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308980  If this is acceptable, it may be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can load a double-struck or outline font of your choice and use its symbols as delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Font available from:
% https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/library-3-am
\setfontface\outline{LIBRARY 3 AM}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase]
  
\newcommand\llparen{\mathopen{\textnormal{\outline (}}}
\newcommand\rrparen{\mathclose{\textnormal{\outline )}}}
\newcommand\llbrack{\mathopen{\textnormal{\outline [}}}
\newcommand\rrbrack{\mathclose{\textnormal{\outline ]}}}
\newcommand\llbrace{\mathopen{\textnormal{\outline \textbraceleft}}}
\newcommand\rrbrace{\mathclose{\textnormal{\outline \textbraceright}}}

\newcommand\Parens[1]{%
  \llparen%
  #1%
  \rrparen}

\newcommand\Brackets[1]{%
  \llbrack%
  #1
  \rrbrack}
  
\newcommand\Braces[1]{%
  \llbrace%
  #1%
  \rrbrace}

\pagestyle{empty} % Format the MWE for TeX.SX

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
 \llbrace\llbrack\llparen \mathbb R \rrparen\rrbrack\rrbrace \\
 \Braces{\Brackets{\Parens{\mathbb C}}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Library 3AM sample]

This template does not enable scaling, which would be much more complicated.  Unfortunately, although you can set a blackboard font with `\setmathfontface`, `unicode-math` will not substitute it for `()`, `{}` or `[]`.

You could, however, define `\bigllparen`, `\biggrrbrace`, etc., which scale the delimiters, and build size-changing commands from that.