# Matrix in double-struck square bracket style

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, brackets, mathtools

We can use `\llbracket \rrbracket` using the `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` to generate double bracket. My question is:

how we can generate a matrix with double bracket (in the same style as the `\llbracket \rrbracket` version)?

Edit:
I just come up with the following way to make a vector form with two dimension:

```
\providecommand{\matbrack}[2]{
\left\llbracket
\begin{matrix}
    #1 \\
    #2
\end{matrix}
\right\rrbracket
}
```

Inside text:

```
$\vecbrack{M}{1}$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest generalizing the command you have in mind by making it take just 1 argument. That way, it can be used for scalars, column and row vectors of arbitrary length, and entire matrices. I would also like to suggest creating a variant of the `smallmatrix` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) that's surrounded by double-struck brackets, for use in inline math settings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'matrix' env.
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % for '\llbracket' and '\rrbracket'

\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{%
    \left\llbracket \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right\rrbracket}
% for use in inline math:
\newenvironment{bbsmallmatrix}{% 
    \left\llbracket\begin{smallmatrix}}{%
    \end{smallmatrix}\right\rrbracket}

\begin{document}
aaa $\bbrack{ M \\ 1 }$ zzz
\quad
aaa $\begin{bbsmallmatrix} M \\ 1 \end{bbsmallmatrix}$ zzz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Mico: Excellent. Especially the ``bbsmallmatrix". :)

Answer (score 4):

These brackets are `\lBrack` and `\rBrack` in `unicode-math`, `stix` or `stix2`.  A simple example of use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Brack}{\lBrack}{\rBrack}
\newenvironment{bbmatrix}%
  {\left\lBrack\begin{matrix}}%
  {\end{matrix}\right\rBrack}

\begin{document}
\[ \Brack{ \rho, \vartheta, \varphi } 
   \begin{bbmatrix}
   a &b &c \\
   d &e &f \\
  \alpha & \beta & \gamma
   \end{bbmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

Comment: Good answer, but the unicode-math package give some problems to me. SO I've combined with @Mico's anwer and use stmaryrd package and commands \rrbracket and \llbracket instead of  \lBrack and \rBrack

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553473/229863) above, if you do **NOT** want to use the `stmaryrd` package, you can define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{{
  \mathchoice
    {\left\lbrack\!\!\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack\!\!\right\rbrack} % display style
    {\left\lbrack\!\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack\!\right\rbrack} % text style
    {} % script style
    {} % scriptscript style
  }
}
```

to handle arbitrary length scalars, vectors, and matrices. This has the added benefit of looking like `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`.

[image: Example output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{{
  \mathchoice
    {\left\lbrack\!\!\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack\!\!\right\rbrack} % display style
    {\left\lbrack\!\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack\!\right\rbrack} % text style
    {} % script style
    {} % scriptscript style
  }
}

\begin{document}

Inline style: $\bbrack{\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{M}}$

With inline small matrix: $\bbrack{ \begin{smallmatrix} M \\ 1 \end{smallmatrix}}$

Finally, normal display style would look like,

\begin{equation}
\bbrack{
  \begin{matrix} 
    0 & D & 0 & 0 & M & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    M & 0 & 0 & 0 & M & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & M & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & M & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & M & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \varphi & M & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & M & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & M & 0 & \dots & 0\\
  \end{matrix}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```