# Typeseeting a multiset with double curly braces

Tags: math-mode

I like to typeset a multi set with double curly braces, i.e., `$\{\{A,B,C\}\}$`. Unfortunalty, I think the space  between two braces are too large and I could not find a special symbol in *symbols*.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and, may be relevant, depending on how flexible the look is for what you seek in a "special symbol".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The space between the delimiter symbols can be reduced by negative space, e.g. via `\!`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\{\{A, B, C\}\!\}$

$\{\!\{A, B, C\}\!\}$

$\{\!\!\{A, B, C\}\!\!\}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\!` is defined as:

```
\def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip}
```

and `\thinmuskip` has the value:

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\ldblbrace}{\{\mskip-5mu\{}
\newcommand*{\rdblbrace}{\}\mskip-5mu\}}
\begin{document}
$\ldblbrace A, B, C \rdblbrace$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Package `stix` defines braces with vertical lines. However, the package does change many math symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$\lBrace A, B, C\rBrace$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result stix]

Version, which only imports `\lBrace` and `\rBrace` from `stix` without changing other symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{stix}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{stix}{%
}{%
  \DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{stix@largesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{stix@largesymbols}{bold}{LS2}{stixex}{b}{n}
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrace}{\mathopen} {stix@largesymbols}{"E8}%
                                            {stix@largesymbols}{"0E}
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrace}{\mathclose}{stix@largesymbols}{"E9}%
                                            {stix@largesymbols}{"0F}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\lBrace A, B, C\rBrace$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with \lBrace, \rBrace from stix]