# \input{glyphtounicode} with \pdfgentounicode=1 creates unwanted hyperlinks from link-like text

Tags: hyperref, links

I often use `\input{glyphtounicode}  \pdfgentounicode=1` to generate PDF-files whose contents [paste with the correct Unicode codepoints](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64188/14996). However I noticed that as a side effect of these commands, some weblinks are created that I didn't explicit call for (using for example `hyperref`).

```
\documentclass{article}

% If at least one of the following two lines is omitted,
% the two text strings won't generate weblinks.
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1


\begin{document}

www.google.com

http://www.google.com/

\end{document}
```

If either of the two relevant commands above is omitted, `www.google.com` and `http://www.google.com/` will not appear as hyperlinks in the generated PDF-file. (I use Adobe Reader to view them.) Why? How can I prevent these text strings from producing hyperlinks?

Comment: Ask adobe (assuming you are using adobe reader). Obviously the reader is guessing that these are links.

Comment: a lot of others PDF viewer assume that and it can be disabled in the prefences of the viewer.

Comment: @Herbert Why do these links not appear when one of the two commands above is commented out? It must be more complicated than that. Also, if I for example replace the two lines in the preamble by `\usepackage{hyperref}`, no links are created.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yep, I'm using Adobe Reader, thanks for pointing me to this detail. It will be good to hear from people using other PDF-readers about this case.

Comment: If I try with `xpdf` I see no link, so it's a previewer's feature.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: The reader is using the *names* of the glyphs to decide if a sequence of glyphs is a link or not. So everything that change this names can affect the heuristic. E.g. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}` "creates" links too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Why are these links generated?

In this case, Adobe Reader is deducing that they are links.
(Ulrike Fischer) But this is **viewer-dependent**: the TeXworks viewer doesn't produce automatic links, but Preview does (and even without `glyphtounicode.tex`'s mechanics). (Joseph Wright)

### How can I prevent these text strings from producing hyperlinks?

For Adobe Reader XI, one can enable or disable the following checkbox: `Preferences` → `General` → `Basic Tools` → `Create links from URLs`.

### Why is link creation dependent on the two commands `\input{glyphtounicode}` and `\pdfgentounicode=1`?

> The reader is using the *names* of the glyphs to decide whether a sequence of glyphs is a link. Usage of the glyph names depends on these two crucial lines.
>   (adapted from Ulrike Fischer)

---

The most important parts from `glyphtounicode.tex` seem to be the following lines:

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{a}{0061}
\pdfglyphtounicode{b}{0062}
...
\pdfglyphtounicode{z}{007A}
```

and

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{colon}{003A}
\pdfglyphtounicode{slash}{002F}
\pdfglyphtounicode{period}{002E}
```

Without `colon` or `slash`, the lower text will have only its second part appear as a link. Without `period`, only the lower text is linked, but it is linked in its entirety.

---

The lower-case letters seem to have duplicates

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{Asmall}{0061}
\pdfglyphtounicode{Bsmall}{0062}
...
\pdfglyphtounicode{Zsmall}{007A}
```

that seem to not make a difference.

---

As for the capital letters:

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{A}{0041}
\pdfglyphtounicode{B}{0042}
...
\pdfglyphtounicode{Z}{005A}
```

With

```
WWW.GOOGLE.COM

HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM/
```

the lower but not the upper text will be linked. Without capital letters, `www.GOOGLE.COM` is still recognized. This indicates that the capital letters play a role, but there are some details to explore.

---

---

*Thanks to [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/) for significant contributions to the solution. [Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/) deserves credit for an idea and [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/) for data points.*