# Working on Resume Template why does "ti" in anyword get converted to "Ɵ" when copying from pdf or pdf parsed to txt

Tags: resume

I am fairly new to latex , I tried it for my resume on Overleaf , i am using this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/rahulworld-resume/pxynfdjpdryc

but whenever i copy text from pdf it has unwanted symbols like
statasƟcal for statastical ,
I did a search and found that by using
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
it would work but when i use this resume formatting is ruined and font is also changed completely
Please help me with it
As it is giving me problems on ATS for resume and my resume is not getting me through.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I guess that in the PDF, there is a ligature joining the t and the i. When this occurs, either replace the faulty letters, use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182791/184389) or do not copy paste.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding/Removing ligature from Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182747/finding-removing-ligature-from-tex)

Comment: According to the tag of your template it is for xelatex. If you are using this engine, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is wrong. But I won't download and install an external template to check which font setup it uses. Ask the author of the template for help.

Comment: @KersouMan this does not look like a duplicate of that question, there the ligatures are inside the LaTeX source, whereas in this case the ligature is in the pdf only (and the source contains `ti`).

Comment: @nikhildsahu if it is indeed a ligature then you can try some of the suggestions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439651/how-do-i-disable-ligatures to switch it off, for example writing `stat\/ist\/ical` instead of `statistical`.

Comment: @Marijn What I understand from the OP's question is that some text is copy/pasted from a PDF file into a LaTeX source that, when compiled, provokes unwanted characters. My guess is that the OP is copying ligatured characters from the PDF source into a LaTeX document and that the compiler does not know it. It happened to me in LaTeX text that someone had copy/pasted from a PDF and that contained ligatured f and i that where not separated into an f and an i in the text editor, but where a different unicode character.

Comment: @KersouMan I understand it differently: the OP uploads his compiled pdf resume into an applicant tracking system (ATS) that extracts plain text from the pdf which does not work for ligatures, or, the OP manually copies the text in his resume from the pdf into the system which gives errors (however in that case it would be easy to manually fix the error). So the ligature is not in the original LaTeX source and also is not re-introduced into the LaTeX source in any way. But maybe I misunderstand, only the OP can clarify.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting some helpful materials , but this does not solve my problem , whenever I try to copy from my compiled PDF , the ti  becomes  Ɵ , @Marjin technique worked of t\/i , but I want a better way to this , as it will tedious to replace ti to t\/i

Comment: Thanks for help , I got  it solved by changing to LuaLatex from Xelatex in overleaf