# How to type French character in LaTeX

Tags: accents, french

I would like to insert "ç".
Tried including `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`,
and type `\c {c}` , but doesn't work.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc

Comment: you don't say how this doesn't work, so i'm guessing.  if you redefined `\c` you would get either an error or surprising output; i'd check for that first.  but of course if you have the letter on your keyboard, it's easiest to use that if you're using `inputenc` with an appropriate option.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you load `inputenc` with the `utf8` encoding option (make sure that your editor is also configured to use Unicode), you can input those characters directly from your keyboard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Ç et ç
\end{document}
```

[image]

A few comments (added by [herve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16979/herve)):

If your keyboard has  not a french layout, the way to input it are (on a mac using international keyboard: alt+c , on a linux box compose followed by coma followed by c.

`\c c` should work without use of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I have some conflicts between packages(I guess.) I further added  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and it finally works. I don't know why though. I typed ç directly in the text.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble [is a good thing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664/8569), 
but sadly [it will load a bitmap font by default](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291/8569).
To fix this, you should [install the cm-super package or load a vector font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1390/8569).

Comment: You are right. The whole text is changed. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: @user16739 It's hard to tell without seeing your actual settings. Perhaps you should open a fresh new question showing a minimal and complete version of your document illustrating the problem. Since the issue of the original question was solved, I don't see why you un-accepted the answer. You can always start follow-up questions for new issues.

Comment: It's not solved.\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}--those three package couldhelp insert ç, but they also change the other English characters. If I omit one package, error occurs.

Comment: @user16739 The title of your question says "How to type French character in Latex" and that was solved. As I said, if you have new issues (and the font issue is new since it wasn't mentioned in the original question), please open a follow-up question.

Comment: @user16739 Whether you decide to open a new question, or to keep this one, please add to your question a minimal and complete version of a document illustrating your problem. Otherwise, it will be almost impossible to provide effective help.

Comment: I would keep this one. This is finally solved. Thank you. I defined some symbols and they conflict with \c. Thanks again.

Answer (score 19):

Simply `\c{c}`, no space.

I believe you are trying a space between `\c` and `{c}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most of our site.

Comment: This can't be the problem: space after command sequences is automatically gobbled.  `\c c`, `\c {c}`, and `\c{c}` are treated the same (provided '`\`', '`c`', '`{`', '`}`', and '` `' have the usual catcodes).

Answer (score 1):

On Mac the following works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Ç ç é É üäö
\end{document}
```