# How to Edit newlfm

Tags: letters, newlfm

I found a perfect template in latex that fits my need. But I am struggling to make it look exactly the way I want. The template is [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/long-lined-cover-letter). This template is using `newlfm`. This is the code:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Long Lined Cover Letter
    % LaTeX Template
    % Version 1.0 (1/6/13)
    %
    % This template has been downloaded from:
    % http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
    %
    % Original author:
    % Matthew J. Miller
    % http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/
    %
    % License:
    % CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

    \usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

    \newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
    \makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

    \newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
    \newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
    \newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
    \PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
    \PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

    \lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \namefrom{John Smith} % Name

    \addrfrom{
    \today\\[12pt] % Date
    123 Broadway \\ % Address
    City, State 12345
    }

    \phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

    \emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
    \closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

    \nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith} % Addressee of the letter above the to address

    \addrto{
    Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
    The Corporation \\
    123 Pleasant Lane \\
    City, State 12345
    }

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{document}
    \begin{newlfm}

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   LETTER CONTENT
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

    PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your qualifications, training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life. 

    PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking time to consider your credentials. 

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

I want to make it look like this:
[image]
The from is `up-left` and the to is `down right`.
Can you please help me to edit this code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consult the documentation of the class `newlfm` you will find the list of options needed to do what you want. Add the following options to your `\documentclass` statement.

```
\documentclass[...,orderdatefromto,dateleft,addrfromleft,addrtoright]{newlfm}
```

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Long Lined Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (1/6/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Matthew J. Miller
% http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft,orderdatefromto,dateleft,addrfromleft,addrtoright]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{John Smith} % Name

\addrfrom{
\today\\[12pt] % Date
123 Broadway \\ % Address
City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith} % Addressee of the letter above the to address

\addrto{
Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
The Corporation \\
123 Pleasant Lane \\
City, State 12345
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
Contents of letter
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please help me to write this letter in french ?

Comment: @dmx What do you mean? Translating English words and phrases inserted automatically by `newlfm` to French? If you see such a phrase, say `FAX Cover Page`, search for this string in `newlfm.cls`, and you will find a line `\PhrFAXcovp{FAX Cover Page}`. This means you have to add `\PhrFAXcovp{XYZ}` to your preamble in order to change `FAX Cover Page` to `XYZ`. In the sample letter above there are two examples of such custumizations, see `\PhrPhone{Phone}` and `\PhrEmail{Email}`.

Comment: Translate in french and allow character such as é, à, ...

Comment: @dmx Check webpages like [Document en français avec LaTeX (babel)](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/latex-in-french.html), [How to type French character in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64852/110998).  Typically you will need to set the input encoding to `latin1` or `utf8` using `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`; moreover, `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` will give French dates, French translations of common strings like `chapter`, and French typography.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `article`-based version of your [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) template. It allows for easy changes and is therefore far more flexible than your current setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Default header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Default footer rule
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}% Your logo here

\hrulefill

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} l @{}}
  \today\\[12pt] % Date
  123 Broadway \\ % Address
  City, State 12345 \\
  Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
  Email: john@smith.com
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}}
  Mrs. Jane Smith \\ % Addressee of the letter above the to address
  Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
  The Corporation \\
  123 Pleasant Lane \\
  City, State 12345
\end{tabular}
\hspace*{7em}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

Dear Mrs.\ Smith,% greeting

\bigskip

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you 
are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e.\ 
career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, 
services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent 
graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the 
position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique 
qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. 
Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your qualifications, 
training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by 
providing details which bring your experiences to life. 

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time 
and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy 
response. For example, state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a 
certain date and would like to set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call 
on a certain date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking 
time to consider your credentials. 

\vspace{\baselineskip}

Sincerely yours,% Closing text

\vspace{5\baselineskip}

John Smith

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please help me to write this letter in french ?