# MikTeX for MS Windows seems to use Type3 (raster) fonts when instructed to use Type1 (vector)

Tags: fonts, miktex, font-encodings

I use MikTeX as my compiler for Windows. The problem is that it uses Type3 (raster) fonts even though I've stated:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble.

As far as I've understood, this will force the compiler to use vector fonts instead.

Have I misunderstood something? Can I reconfigure my installation to always use vector fonts?

Comment: You should install also the CM-super package.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically

Comment: `T1` is *not* a shortcut for `type1`, it doesn't describe the font format but the font encoding. `T1` encoded fonts can be bitmaps, or type1, or ttf, or ....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Just for the record: (Adobe) Type 3 are outline fonts just like Type 1 but with expanded capabilities.

Comment: In addition to Peter Jansson: [Wikipedia: PostScript fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `\usepackage{lmodern}` or install the `cm-super` fonts

Comment: Is that required? When I compile documents on OS X using MacTeX or on Linux using TeXLive the results are vector based using the exact same source code. When I use my university installation of MiKTeX it also works just fine.

Comment: Texlive installations are commonly (not always) complete installations with all packages. MikTex on the other hand installs only a minimum of packages and you can install some of them later. If your Uni has installed all MikTeX packges and if you used a full Texlive before, it is likely that the cm-super packages was used without you knowing

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the font (e.g. defined by a template).

Install `cm-super` as written [earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98709/110064): (do not edit the tex-file)

[image: MikTeX cm-super]

source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/547309/110064