# MiKTeX 2.9 Texmaker: Text in PDF not vectorized ... but formulas and tables are vectorized

Tags: fonts, math-mode, pdf

Users,

i am new to LaTeX and i found something that is really strage.

When i create a PDF from the following code, the text is not vectorized while formulas and tables are. I am using MiKTeX 2.9, TeXMaker 4.3 on a Windows 7 Notebook. To view the PDF i am using Acrobat Reader.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

% language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 

\title{Testpage}
\author{Max Mueller}
\date{11.09.2014}

% begin of printed stuff
\begin{document}

%\tableofcontents

%Überkapitel
%\part{Name of Part}
%\chapter{Name of Chapter}
\section{Abc abc abc}
\subsection{Abc abc abc}
Text is not vectorized ... but formulas and tables are vectorized $ \exp{ix} = \cos{x} + i\sin{x}$
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your suggestions :).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no special about your code which should lead to non-vectorized text

Comment: Could you explain a bit more 'vectorized'? I think you mean that the fonts used are not in Type1 format but rather are bitmap, but am not sure. If that is the case, do you have `cm-super` installed?

Comment: See _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98708/miktex-for-ms-windows-seems-to-use-type3-raster-fonts-when-instructed-to-use-t/

Comment: Add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you that solves my problem :). Now its vectorized, hence i can zoom in and the text is still smooth :). Thank you alot.