# Math font pixellated cmbright

Tags: fonts, pixelated

I have some problems using the package cmbright. It renders pixelated maths symbols. I don't understand since the package is installed in miktex. I compile using pdflatex

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{cmbright}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Hey!$\lambda\beta\gamma$
\end{document}
```

Here is the output of upmap --verbose

[image]

Comment: I guess it's the usual problem of MiKTeX not updating correctly the map files when Type1 fonts are installed.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I update the map file :)?

Comment: Using TeX Live instead of MiKTeX? Just joking. `;-)` Sorry, but I can't help you. Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation

Comment: Run from the command line (as administrator and as user) `updmap --verbose`. The switch will let you see which fonts are mentioned in the psfonts databases (`psfonts.map` and its siblings).

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I ran the command but it didn't change the pixelated effect. Do you want me to post the output?

Answer (score 8):

Your problem comes from the fact that the `cmbright` package doesn't include type 1 version of the fonts. The type 1 versions spread over the `cm-super` (for T1 and TS1 font encodings) and `hfbright`packages. Unfortunately `hfbright.map` is *not* mentioned in the default `updmap.cfg`. I'll report the problem to Christian Schenk. So for now, you'll have to mention it in your personal updmap.cfg. If you don't already have one, you'll to create one, with these lines (or add them if it exists):

```
# hfbright : type 1 version of cmbright (OT1 encoding and maths)
Map hfbright.map
```

This file  should be located in `C:\Users\Your_Name\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\conf\`

Then run `updmap`, as I said in my comment. It works (note that the text part is pixellated, as I haven't installed `cm-super`):

[image]

Comment: If `hfbright.map` exists on the system, then adding `\pdfmapfile{=htbright.map}` to the document should work without requiring a run of `updmap`.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information. There remains however that hfbright.map *should* be mentioned in the `system` updmap.cfg.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, of course. I've seen several problems with MiKTeX not updating the map files correctly on our site.

Comment: @egreg: I've mentioned some of them, I think. There are two kinds of problems: most of the time, the .map file *is* mentioned in the system updmap.cfg (even if the font is not installed, as is normal), but updmap.exe is not run at installation, for some reason. It suffices for the user to run it from the command line. The second case is when the .map file is not even mentioned, although it is installed. It's hard for a basic user to understand what's happening, and it should be reported to MiKTeX's site on SourceForge. I did it for this particular case.

Comment: I had the same problem with *MiKTeX 2.9* on Windows, but this was fixed when i installed the packages `cm-super` and `hfbright` of *MiKTeX Package Manager*. I don't need to modify any *internal file*.

Comment: @skpblack: on my system, neither cm-super nor hfbright were installed, and I only installed the latter for testing, and the system updmap.cfg mentions only cm-super. Which version do you have?

Comment: On my system appears `# hfbright` and in the next line `MixedMap hfbright.map` in *updmap.cfg*

Comment: @skpblack: perhaps you did a full installation? I don't know how to explain. My system is regularly updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the font (e.g. defined by a template). Install cm-super as written earlier: (do not edit the tex-file)
[image: MikTeX cm-super]

source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546882/110064