# Must I install cm-super to get a smooth CM Bright font?

Tags: fonts, packages

I've been using the CM Bright font for some homework assignments. I've found its very pixelated when zooming in. I hope these images display that.

[image: Far out image]

[image: Closer up]

I've found a similar post [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206735/math-font-pixellated-cmbright) asking for help, but that one speaks on installing `cm-super` and `hfbright` to get a smooth looking font. Does everyone who use the CM Bright fonts do the same?

Comment: cm-super is installed by default in texlive, why wouldn't you install it?

Comment: If you have the commercial versions of the CM Bright fonts, you don't need the free versions. Otherwise, in TeX Live, type1 fonts are provided by `cm-super` and `hfbright` and you will need these to get scalable fonts. If you're only interested in printing, you may not need type1 for good results, depending on which sizes you need. But `cmbright` only contains metafont sources, which don't work well on screen. In TeX Live, `tlmgr info cmbright` provides (most of) this information.

Comment: @cfr Do you know where are the commercial CM Bright fonts available, or available at all? The Micropress sites seems down.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis No idea, sorry.