# mu (\micro) symbol in siunitx package is badly aliased

Tags: fonts, siunitx, greek

I'm using the `siunitx` package to display units, but I'm having a problem with the appearance of the Greek letter mu that results from the `\micro` command. The version in the package documentation looks like this:

[image: mu from siunitx documentation]

but the version from my MWE (shown below) looks like this:

[image: mu from mwe]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

What do I need to do to get an upright mu in the `siunitx` package without the aliasing?

Comment: [No problem here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TEVz9.png).

Comment: @Werner That's very strange. Any idea how it could be different for me? I'm using Miktex and TeXnicCenter if it makes a difference.

Comment: Is cm-super installed in you miktex? Cm-super is the default in Texlive but for some reason one has to ask for it on miktex, thus he default font is not "smooth", at that is what I think the problem is. Haven't used miktex for years

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Please do not use `minimal` for MWEs. You can search this site for explanations.
2. The command for your output would be `\si{\micro\metre}` but I guess you know this.
3. In order to get the font unpixeled, you have to install `cm-super`

   - Go to Start - All Programs - MiKTeX 2.9 - Maintenance - MiKTeX Package Manager
   - Search for "cm-super" in the first field with name "Name"
   - Right click the only package and hit "install".
4. The font used for the `\mu` in the manual is another font, though. If you want to change to another font, just search the manual for the words "text-micro" and "math-micro" in order to find introductions on this.

---

If you want the output as in the manual, you have to do:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo} % 'o'ld 's'tyle 'f'igures are used in the manual, but you can leave this away, of course. 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \si{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do we have a general 'you need `cm-super` with MiKTeX' question/answer, I wonder.

Comment: @JosephWright That would be good. In fact I needed a long time to get that and always put `\usepackage{lmodern}` to many answers of mine. This one perhaps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98708 Could you tell me (or BZ1) if you are using `\sisetup{math-micro = \fontspec{Minion Pro} \textmu, text-micro = \fontspec{Minion Pro} \textmu}` in your manual? Just to make this here complete. Thanks.

Comment: Looks as good as any: great. In terms of the manual, it uses `mathpazo` (its compiled with pdfTeX): I don't own Minion Pro and it would make distribution tricky.

Comment: @JosephWright: Perhaps [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1291/5764)